# Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script

Tags: scripting, parameters, batch-file, escaping, quotes

How would I go about replacing all of the double quotes in my batch file's parameters with escaped double quotes? This is my current batch file, which expands all of its command line parameters inside the string:

```
@echo off
call bash --verbose -c "g++-linux-4.1 %*"
```

It then uses that string to make a call to Cygwin's bash, executing a Linux cross-compiler. Unfortunately, I'm getting parameters like these passed in to my batch file:

```
"launch-linux-g++.bat" -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions 
-Wno-inline -Wall  -DNDEBUG   -c 
-o "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Testing\SparseLib\bin\Win32\LinuxRelease\hello.o" 
"c:\Users\Me\Documents\Testing\SparseLib\SparseLib\hello.cpp"
```

Where the first quote around the first path passed in is prematurely ending the string being passed to GCC, and passing the rest of the parameters directly to bash (which fails spectacularly.)

I imagine if I can concatenate the parameters into a single string then escape the quotes it should work fine, but I'm having difficulty determining how to do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Google eventually came up with the answer. The syntax for string replacement in batch is this:

```
set v_myvar=replace me
set v_myvar=%v_myvar:ace=icate%
```

Which produces "replicate me". My script now looks like this:

```
@echo off
set v_params=%*
set v_params=%v_params:"=\"%
call bash -c "g++-linux-4.1 %v_params%"
```

Which replaces all instances of `"` with `\"`, properly escaped for bash.

Answer (score 121):

The escape character in batch scripts is `^`.  But for double-quoted strings, double up the quotes:

```
"string with an embedded "" character"
```

Comment: doubling quotes did *not* work for me, but ^ worked like a champ.

Comment: `^` is the escape character only in _unquoted_ strings; in double-quoted strings, it is treated as a literal.
Unlike Unix (POSIX-like) shells, `cmd.exe` offers NO standardized _shell_ treatment of double quotes inside a double quoted string, and _interpretation is left to the program being invoked_ (cont'd in next comment).

Comment: (cont'd from previous comment)
In practice, _most_ executables / script interpreters apply the C convention of expecting `"` chars. to be escaped as `\"` inside a double-quoted string (applies at least to: C/C++, Python, Perl, Ruby).
By contrast, `""` is only recognized in the _minority_ of cases: 
In parameters passed to batch files, `""` _is_ recognized as an _embedded_ double quote, but is _retained as is_ in the corresponding `%<n>` parameter, even after removing the _enclosing_ double quotes with `%~<n>`.
Python graciously _also_ recognizes `""`, as an alternative to `\"`.

Answer (score 116):

[eplawless's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script#562131) simply and effectively solves his specific problem: it replaces all `"` instances in the entire argument list with `\"`, which is how Bash requires double-quotes inside a double-quoted string to be represented.

To generally answer the question of **how to escape double-quotes inside a double-quoted string using `cmd.exe`**, the Windows command-line interpreter (whether on the command line - often still mistakenly called the "DOS prompt" - or in a batch file):<sup>See bottom for a look at *PowerShell*.</sup>

**tl;dr**:

**The answer depends on *which program you're calling*:**

- You ***must* use `""`** when passing an argument **to a(nother) *batch file*** and you ***may* use `""` with applications created with *Microsoft*'s C/C++/.NET compilers** (which *also* accept `\"`), which on Windows **includes Python, Node.js**, and **PowerShell (Core) 7+'s [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)** (`pwsh`) but *not Windows PowerShell's* (`powershell.exe`):

  - Example: `foo.bat "We had 3"" of rain."`
- The following applies to targeting **batch files** only:

  - `""` is the only way to get the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) to treat the whole double-quoted string as a *single* argument (though that won't matter if you simply pass *all* arguments *through* to another program, with `%*`)
  - Sadly, however, not only are the enclosing double-quotes retained (as usual), but so are the doubled escaped ones, so obtaining the intended string is a two-step process; e.g., assuming that the double-quoted string is passed as the 1st argument, `%1`:

    - `set "str=%~1"` removes the enclosing double-quotes; `set "str=%str:""="%"` then converts the doubled double-quotes to single ones.
      Be sure to use the enclosing double-quotes around the assignment parts to prevent unwanted interpretation of the values.
- **`\"` is *required* - as the *only* option - by many other programs**, (e.g., Ruby, Perl, PHP, as well as programs that use the  [`CommandLineToArgv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) Windows API function to parse their command-line arguments), but **it use from `cmd.exe` is *not robust and safe***:

  - `\"` is what many executables and interpreters either *require* - including Windows PowerShell - when passed strings *from the outside*, on the command line - or, in the case of **Microsoft's compilers, support *as an alternative to* `""`** - ultimately, though, **it's up to the target program to parse the argument list.**

    - Example: `foo.exe "We had 3\" of rain."`
  - **However, use of `\"` can *break* calls and at least hypothetically result in unwanted, arbitrary execution of commands and/or input/output redirections**:

    - The following characters present this risk: `& | < >`
    - For instance, the following results in unintended execution of the `ver` command; see further below for an explanation and the next bullet point for a workaround:

      - `foo.exe "3\" of snow" "& ver."`
  - **For calling the *Windows PowerShell* [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe`, `\""` and `"^""` are robust, but limited alternatives** (see section "Calling PowerShell's CLI ..." below).
- **If you must use `\"` from `cmd.exe`, there are only 3 *safe* approaches from `cmd.exe`**, which are, however **quite cumbersome**: <sup>Tip of the hat to [T S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2770331/t-s) for his help.</sup>

  - **Using (possibly *selective*) delayed variable expansion** in your batch file, you can **store literal `\"` in a *variable* and reference that variable inside a `"..."` string using `!var!` syntax** - see [T S's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169953/45375).

    - The above approach, despite being cumbersome, has the advantage that you can apply it *methodically* and that it works *robustly*, with any input.
  - **Only with LITERAL strings - ones NOT involving VARIABLES - do you get a similarly methodical approach: categorically `^`-escape *all* `cmd.exe` metacharacters:** `" & | < >` and - if you also want to suppress variable expansion - `%`:
    `foo.exe ^"3\^" of snow^" ^"^& ver.^"`
  - Otherwise, you must **formulate your string based on recognizing which portions of the string `cmd.exe` considers *unquoted* due to misinterpreting `\"`** as closing delimiters:

    - in *literal* portions containing shell metacharacters:  `^`-escape  them; using the example above, it is `&` that must be `^`-escaped:
      `foo.exe "3\" of snow" "^& ver."`
    - in portions *with `%...%`-style variable references*: ensure that `cmd.exe` considers them part of a `"..."` string *and* that that the variable values do not themselves have embedded, unbalanced quotes - **which is not even always possible**.

---

#### Background

<sup>Note: This is based on my own experiments. Do let me know if I'm wrong.</sup>

POSIX-like shells such as Bash on **Unix-like systems** tokenize the argument list (string) before passing arguments *individually* to the target program: among other expansions, they split the argument list into individual words (word splitting) and remove quoting characters from the resulting words (quote removal). **The target program is handed an *array* of *individual, verbatim arguments***, i.e. with ***syntactic* quotes removed**.

**By contrast, the Windows command interpreter apparently does not tokenize the argument list and simply passes the *single* string comprising *all* arguments - including quoting chars. - to the target program.**
However, *some* preprocessing takes place before the single string is passed to the target program: `^` escape chars. outside of double-quoted strings are removed (they escape the following char.), and variable references (e.g., `%USERNAME%`) are *interpolated* first.

Thus, unlike in Unix, it is the target program's responsibility to parse to parse the arguments string and break it down into individual arguments with quotes removed.
Thus, **different programs can require differing escaping methods** and **there's no single escaping mechanism that is *guaranteed* to work with all programs** - <sup>https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094897/45375 contains excellent background on the anarchy that is Windows command-line parsing.</sup>

**In practice, `\"` is very common, but NOT SAFE from `cmd.exe`**, as mentioned above:

Since `cmd.exe` itself doesn't recognize `\"` as an *escaped* double-quote, it can misconstrue later tokens on the command line as *unquoted* and potentially interpret them as *commands* and/or *input/output redirections*.
**In a nutshell: the problem surfaces, if any of the following characters follow an *opening or unbalanced* `\"`: `& | < >`**; for example:

```
foo.exe "3\" of snow" "& ver."
```

`cmd.exe` sees the following tokens, resulting from misinterpreting `\"` as a regular double-quote:

- `"3\"`
- `of`
- `snow" "`
- rest: `& ver.`

Since `cmd.exe` thinks that `& ver.` is *unquoted*, it interprets it as `&` (the command-sequencing operator), followed by the name of a command to execute (`ver.` - the `.` is ignored; `ver` reports `cmd.exe`'s version information).
The overall effect is:

- First, `foo.exe` is invoked with the first *3* tokens only.
- Then, command `ver` is executed.

Even in cases where the accidental command does no harm, your overall command won't work as designed, given that not all arguments are passed to it.

**Many compilers / interpreters recognize ONLY `\"`** - e.g., the GNU C/C++ compiler, Perl, Ruby, PHP, as well as programs that use the  [`CommandLineToArgv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) Windows API function to parse their command-line arguments - and for them **there is no simple solution to this problem.**
Essentially, you'd have to know in advance which portions of your command line are misinterpreted as unquoted, and selectively `^`-escape all instances of `& | < >` in those portions.

By contrast, **use of `""` is SAFE**, but is **regrettably only supported by Microsoft-compiler-based executables and batch files** (in the case of batch files, with the quirks discussed above), which notable excludes *PowerShell* - see next section.

---

#### Calling PowerShell's CLI from `cmd.exe` or POSIX-like shells:

Note: See the bottom section for how quoting is handled *inside* PowerShell.

When invoked **from the outside** - e.g., from `cmd.exe`, whether from the command line or a batch file:

- ***PowerShell [Core] v6+* now properly recognizes `""`** (in addition to `\"`), which is both **safe to use and whitespace-preserving**.

  - `pwsh -c " ""a &  c"".length "` doesn't break and correctly yields `6`
- ***Windows PowerShell*** (the legacy edition whose latest and *final* version is 5.1)  **recognizes *only* `\"` or `"""`**,  the latter being the **most robust choice *from `cmd.exe`*, in the form `"^"""`** (even though *internally* PowerShell uses `` ` `` as the escape character in double-quoted strings and also accepts `""` - see bottom section), as discussed next:

Calling ***Windows PowerShell*** **from `cmd.exe`** / a batch file:

- **`""` *breaks***, because it is fundamentally unsupported:

  - `powershell -c " ""ab  c"".length "` -> error "The string is missing the terminator"
- `\"` and `"""` **work *in principle*, but aren't *safe***:

  - `powershell -c " \"ab  c\".length "` works as intended: it outputs `5` (note the *2* spaces)
  - But it isn't safe, because `cmd.exe` metacharacters break the command, unless escaped:
    `powershell -c " \"a&  c\".length "` *breaks*, due to the `&`, which would have to be escaped as `^&`
- `\""` is ***safe*, but *normalizes interior whitespace***, which can be undesired:
- `powershell -c " \""a&  c\"".length "` outputs `4`(!), because the 2 spaces are normalized to 1.
- **`"^""` is the best choice for *Windows PowerShell*, specifically** <sup>Credit goes to [Venryx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2441655/venryx) for discovering this approach.</sup> and **`""` for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**:

  - Windows PowerShell: `powershell -c " "^""a&  c"^"".length "` *works*: doesn't break - despite `&` - *and* outputs `5`, i.e., correctly preserved whitespace.
  - PowerShell *Core*: `pwsh -c """a&  c"".length "`
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for more information.

On **Unix-like platforms** (Linux, macOS), when calling **PowerShell [Core]**'s CLI, `pwsh`, from a POSIX-like shell such as `bash`:

You ***must* use `\"`**, which, however is **both safe and whitespace-preserving**:

```bash
$ pwsh -c " \"a&  c\".length " # OK: 5

# Alternative, with '...' quoting: no escaping of " needed.
$ pwsh -c ' "a&  c".length ' # OK: 5
```

---

#### Related information

- **`^` can only be used as the escape character in *unquoted* strings** - inside double-quoted strings, `^` is not special and treated as a literal.

  - **CAVEAT**: **Use of `^` in parameters passed to the `call` statement is broken** (this applies to both uses of `call`: invoking another batch file or binary, and calling a subroutine in the same batch file):

    - **`^` instances in *double-quoted* values are *inexplicably doubled***, altering the value being passed: e.g., if variable `%v%` contains literal value `a^b`, `call :foo "%v%"` assigns `"a^^b"`(!) to `%1` (the first parameter) in subroutine `:foo`.
    - ***Unquoted* use of `^` with `call` is *broken altogether* in that `^` can no longer be used to escape special characters**: e.g., `call foo.cmd a^&b` quietly breaks (instead of passing literal `a&b` too `foo.cmd`, as would be the case without `call`) - `foo.cmd` is never even invoked(!), at least on Windows 7.
- **Escaping a literal `%` is a special case**, unfortunately, which **requires distinct syntax depending on whether a string is specified on the *command line* vs. *inside a batch file***; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375

  - The short of it: Inside a batch file, use `%%`. On the command line, `%` cannot be escaped, but if you place a `^` at the start, end, or inside a variable name in an *unquoted* string (e.g., `echo %^foo%`), you can prevent variable expansion (interpolation); `%` instances on the command line that are not part of a variable reference are treated as literals (e.g, `100%`).
- Generally, **to safely work with variable values that may contain spaces and special characters**:

  - **Assignment**: **Enclose *both* the variable name and the value in a *single* pair of double-quotes**; e.g., `set "v=a & b"` assigns literal value `a & b` to variable `%v%` (by contrast, `set v="a & b"` would make the double-quotes part of the value). Escape literal `%` instances as `%%` (works only in batch files - see above).
  - **Reference**: **Double-quote variable references** to make sure their value is not interpolated; e.g., `echo "%v%"` does not subject the value of `%v%` to interpolation and prints `"a & b"` (but note that the double-quotes are invariably printed too). By contrast, `echo %v%` passes literal `a` to `echo`, interprets `&` as the command-sequencing operator, and therefore tries to execute a command named `b`.
    Also note the above caveat re use of `^` with the `call` statement.

    - *External* programs typically take care of removing enclosing double-quotes around parameters, but, as noted, in batch files you have to do it yourself (e.g., `%~1` to remove enclosing double-quotes from the 1st parameter) and, sadly, **there is no direct way that I know of to get `echo` to print a variable value faithfully *without* the enclosing double-quotes**.

      - [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182705/neil) offers **a `for`-based workaround that works *as long as the value has no embedded double quotes***; e.g.:
        `set "var=^&')|;,%!" for /f "delims=" %%v in ("%var%") do echo %%~v`
- **`cmd.exe` does *not* recognize *single*-quotes** as string delimiters (`'...'`) - they are treated as literals and cannot generally be used to delimit strings with embedded whitespace; also, it follows that the tokens abutting the single-quotes and any tokens in between are treated as unquoted by `cmd.exe` and interpreted accordingly.

  - However, given that target programs ultimately perform their own argument parsing, some programs such as Ruby do recognize single-quoted strings even on Windows; by contrast, C/C++ executables and Perl do *not* recognize them.
    Even if supported by the target program, however, it is not advisable to use single-quoted strings, given that their contents are not protected from potentially unwanted interpretation by `cmd.exe`.

---

#### Quoting from *within* PowerShell:

[Windows PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is a much more advanced shell than `cmd.exe`, and it has been a part of Windows for many years now (and [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) brought the PowerShell experience to macOS and Linux as well).

PowerShell works consistently *internally* with respect to quoting:

- inside double-quoted strings, use `` `" `` or `""` to escape double-quotes
- inside single-quoted strings, use `''` to escape single-quotes

This works on the PowerShell command line and when passing parameters to PowerShell scripts or functions from *within* PowerShell.

(As discussed above, passing an escaped double-quote to PowerShell *from the outside* requires `\"` or, more robustly, `\""` - nothing else works).

**Sadly, when invoking *external* programs from PowerShell, you're faced with the need to both accommodate PowerShell's own quoting rules *and* to escape for the *target* program:**

- This problematic behavior is also discussed and summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375); the [*experimental*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`  feature introduced in PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.5 - assuming it becomes an official feature - will fix this at least for those external programs that accept `\"`.

***Double*-quotes inside *double*-quoted strings**:

Consider string `` "3`" of rain" ``, which PowerShell-internally translates to literal `3" of rain`.

If you want to pass this string to an external program, **you have to apply the target program's escaping *in addition* to PowerShell's**; say you want to pass the string to a C program, which expects embedded double-quotes to be escaped as `\"`:

```
foo.exe "3\`" of rain"
```

Note how *both* `` `" `` - to make PowerShell happy - *and* the `\` - to make the target program happy - must be present.

The same logic applies to invoking a batch file, where `""` must be used:

```
foo.bat "3`"`" of rain"
```

By contrast, embedding ***single*-quotes in a *double*-quoted string** requires no escaping at all.

***Single*-quotes inside *single*-quoted strings** do *not* require *extra* escaping; consider `'2'' of snow'`, which is PowerShell' representation of `2' of snow`.

```
foo.exe '2'' of snow'
foo.bat '2'' of snow'
```

PowerShell translates single-quoted strings to double-quoted ones before passing them to the target program.

However, ***double*-quotes inside *single*-quoted strings**, which do not need escaping for *PowerShell*, do still need to be escaped for the *target program*:

```
foo.exe '3\" of rain'
foo.bat '3"" of rain'
```

PowerShell **v3** introduced the magic **`--%` option**, called the *stop-parsing symbol*, which alleviates some of the pain, by passing anything after it *uninterpreted* to the target program, save for `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references (e.g., `%USERNAME%`), which *are* expanded; e.g.:

```
foo.exe --% "3\" of rain" -u %USERNAME%
```

Note how escaping the embedded `"` as `\"` for the target program only (and not also for PowerShell as `` \`" ``) is sufficient.

However, this approach:

- does not allow for *escaping* `%` characters in order to avoid environment-variable expansions.
- precludes *direct* use of PowerShell variables and expressions; instead, the command line must be built in a string variable in a first step, and then invoked with `Invoke-Expression` in a second.

An *alternative* workaround* that addresses this problem is to call via `cmd /c` with a single argument containing the *entire command line*:

```
cmd /c "foo.exe `"3\`" of rain`" -u $env:USERNAME"
```

---

Thus, despite its many advancements, PowerShell has not made escaping easier when calling *external programs* - on the contrary. It has, however, introduced support for single-quoted strings.

If you don't mind installing a third-party module (authored by me), the [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) (`Install-Module Native`) offers backward- and forward-compatible helper function `ie`, which obviates the need for the extra escaping and contains important accommodations for high-profile CLIs on Windows:

```
# Simply prepend 'ie' to your external-program calls.
ie foo.exe '3" of rain' -u $env:USERNAME
```

Comment: Nice description! But ... `Literal use of ^ in double-quoted strings can, be problematic when applying ~ ...` not really. The tilde only removes outer quotes when present. Loosing of carets is a problem of the handling itself. Normally a `set "param=%~1"` solves this.

Comment: Thanks, @jeb, the problem is indeed not specific to use of `~` - I've updated my answer to reflect my new understanding - please comment, if you spot a problem.
Do you have an explanation for the doubling of `^` that automatically happens when you pass parameters to a `call` statement?

Comment: I can only guess that someone at MS thought it's brilliant. That the doubled carets will be automatically removed in the second parse phase. But this was a big fail, as it doesn't work in quotes and it effectively prevents escaping of any special characters. Like `call echo cat^^&dog` it's not solveable with any amount of carets alone

Comment: Thanks, @jeb, I hadn't even considered the _unquoted_ use of `^` with `call`, which, as you point out, is badly broken. It seems that in `call echo cat^&dog` (single `^` that properly escapes the `&`) the target command (`echo`) is never even invoked(!) - the entire command fails quietly. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice Answer. However, I wouldn't recommend `""` as escaped `"` but always `\"` (See my answer for a less dangerous way to use it from within cmd). I don't know any official documentation that defines `""` as an escaped quote, but at least 2 that mention `\"`: [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) and [VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft.aspx). Although wrong documented, [Win32 api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) follows these rules as well.

Comment: @TS: Thanks. I wasn't _recommending_ anything, however, and instead tried to make it clear that there's _no robust, universal solution_: 
you need to know what quoting _the specific target program_ expects. You don't need official documentation when simple tests will do, at least to verify _de-facto_ behavior. Yes, `\"` works with _more_ target programs.

Comment: In all of this talk, somebody should mention the simple rule `cmd.exe` is actually following, to spiral into all of this complication:  As the command line is processed from ***left-to-right***, the double-quote state simply flips. If there is an ***odd*** number of `"` to the left, you are in a token and the delimiter characters are disabled; if there is an ***even*** number of `"` leftwards, then the delimiters are enabled. This is why you can leave the last `"` off. And `""` doesn't delimit, because while it doesn't ultimately change the odd/even state, there is however no delimiter inside.

Answer (score 12):

As an addition to [mklement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/45375):

Almost all executables accept `\"` as an escaped `"`. Safe usage in cmd however is almost only possible using DELAYEDEXPANSION.
To explicitely send a literal `"` to some process, assign `\"` to an environment variable, and then use that variable, whenever you need to pass a quote. Example:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set q=\"
child "malicious argument!q!&whoami"
```

Note `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` seems to work only within batch files. To get DELAYEDEXPANSION in an interactive session, start `cmd /V:ON`.

If your batchfile does't work with DELAYEDEXPANSION, you can enable it temporarily:

```
::region without DELAYEDEXPANSION

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::region with DELAYEDEXPANSION
set q=\"
echoarg.exe "ab !q! & echo danger"
ENDLOCAL

::region without DELAYEDEXPANSION
```

If you want to pass dynamic content from a variable that contains quotes that are escaped as `""` you can replace `""` with `\"` on expansion:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
foo.exe "danger & bar=region with !dynamic_content:""=\"! & danger"
ENDLOCAL
```

This replacement is not safe with `%...%` style expansion!

<sup>In case of [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562131/2770331) `bash -c "g++-linux-4.1 !v_params:"=\"!"` is the safe version.</sup>

---

If for some reason even temporarily enabling DELAYEDEXPANSION is not an option, read on:

Using `\"` from within cmd is a little bit safer if one always needs to escape special characters, instead of just sometimes. (It's less likely to forget a caret, if it's consistent...)

To achieve this, one precedes any quote with a caret (`^"`), quotes that should reach the child process as literals must additionally be escaped with a backlash (`\^"`). **ALL** shell meta characters must be escaped with `^` as well, e.g. `&` => `^&`; `|` => `^|`; `>` => `^>`; etc.

Example:

```
child ^"malicious argument\^"^&whoami^"
```

Source: [Everyone quotes command line arguments the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/), see "A better method of quoting"

---

To pass dynamic content, one needs to ensure the following:
The part of the command that contains the variable must be considered "quoted" by `cmd.exe` (This is impossible if the variable can contain quotes - **don't write `%var:""=\"%`**). To achieve this, the last `"` before the variable and the first `"` after the variable are not `^`-escaped. cmd-metacharacters between those two `"` must not be escaped. Example:

```
foo.exe ^"danger ^& bar=\"region with %dynamic_content% & danger\"^"
```

**This isn't safe, if `%dynamic_content%` can contain unmatched quotes.**

Comment: Understood, thanks. Yes, categorically `^`-escaping _all_ metacharacters works robustly and can be applied more methodically (yet it is obviously a royal pain in the body part of your choice). I've updated my answer accordingly (and have given you credit).

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you! Yes, it really is a pain. It's annoying and it's still too easy to forget a metacharacter (therefore I mostly use the `!q!` way). Note: Your answer is slightly inconsistent after your last edit: Near the top you say: "Do _not_ use `^"`". Later you use `^"` as part of the workaround. Maybe you could explain both ways? (1) Escaping all metacharacters (more methodically) / (2) Selectively escaping metacharacters in "unquoted" regions (sometimes necessary to pass dynamic content, e.g. `foo.exe ^"danger ^& bar=\"%dynamic_content%\"^"` - this way the variable is quoted for cmd)

Comment: Good point, thanks - answer updated. I've also made it clearer that MS compiler accept both `\"` and `""`. I've linked to your answer for the more involved variable-based approach. Let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: @mklement0 Your answer always made sense :-) I just wanted to give some ideas for possible improvements. I also added the example about `%dynamic_content%` into my answer. Do you think that it is detailed enough or do I have to explain more?

Comment: Thanks, and just to be clear: I appreciate your input and the conversation. You bring up a good point with respect to inclusion of `%....%` variables. I conclude that your delayed-expansion approach is really the only one that - if feasible - works methodically and robustly. Note that with `%...%` references you cannot _guarantee_ that `cmd.exe` will consider such references as being inside `"..."`. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: @mklement0 Changed my answer again to add 'temporarily delayed expansion'. I also included, "that with `%...%` references you cannot guarantee that `cmd.exe` will consider such references as being inside `"..."`". I hope, I got this correct now. If delayed expansion is not an option, do you see any problems with [this](https://github.com/TSlivede/escape-variables-in-batch/blob/master/escape_test.bat) approach? (I won't include it in the answer - it's too messy)

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting me know. Good idea to localize the `setlocal delayedexpansion`, but you should end the block with `endlocal` (no argument). Honestly, my head started spinning looked at your Gist. We're really dealing with edge cases here, and I think future readers will find everything they need between our two answers.

Answer (score -1):

If the string is already within quotes then use another quote to nullify its action.

```
echo "Insert tablename(col1) Values('""val1""')"
```

Answer (score -1):

At Windows 10 21H1.

If from a batch (`.bat`) file I want to run the Everything application, I use `"""` inside double quotes argument:

`"C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe" -search "<"""D:\My spaced folder""" | """Z:\My_non_spaced_folder"""> <*.jpg | *.jpeg | *.avi | *.mp4>"`

Hope it helps.