# Quoting in bash and perl in recursive ssh command

Tags: perl, bash, ssh

I am writing a perl script to login in to a server with ssh and do some shell commands on the server. The problem is that the server is only accessible by first logging into another server.
(I am using password-less login with ssh keys).

The following bash script is working correctly, and illustrates the problem:

```
#! /bin/bash
server1="login.uib.no"
server2="cipr-cluster01"
ssh "$server1" "ssh $server2 \"echo \\\"\\\$HOSTNAME\\\"\""
```

It prints the correct host name to my screen: `cipr-cluster01`. However, when trying to do same thing in Perl:

```
my $server1="login.uib.no";
my $server2="cipr-cluster01";

print qx/ssh "$server1" "ssh $server2 \"echo \\\"\\\$HOSTNAME\\\"\""/;
```

I get the following output: `login.uib.no`. So I guess, there is some problems with the quoting for the perl script..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qx` works like double quotes. You have to backslash some more:

```
print qx/ssh "$server1" "ssh $server2 \"echo \\\\"\\\$HOSTNAME\\\\"\""/;
```

Using single quotes might simplify the command a lot:

```
print qx/ssh "$server1" 'ssh $server2 "echo \\\$HOSTNAME"'/;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! (I also found that `print qx/ssh $server1 \"ssh $server2 \\\"echo \\\\\\\$HOSTNAME\\\"\"/;` is working.. but your commands are simpler).

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the quoting a bit by using the `ProxyCommand` option that tells `ssh` to connect to `$server2` via `$server1`, rather than explicitly running `ssh` on `$server1`.

```
print qx/ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $server1" "$server2" 'echo \$HOSTNAME'/;
```

(There is some residual output from the proxy command (Killed by signal 1) that I'm not sure how to get rid of.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) that is able to do the quoting automatically:

```
my $ssh_gw = Net::OpenSSH->new($gateway);
my $proxy_command = $ssh_gw->make_remote_command({tunnel => 1}, $host, 22);
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, proxy_command => $proxy_command);
$ssh->system('echo $HOSTNAME');
```