# perl regular expression command line running via ssh

Tags: regex, perl, ssh

I'm trying to run a Perl regular expression via ssh however I'm getting an error "**Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.**"

the Perl command I'm trying to execute is

```
perl -p -i '.backup'  -e ' if ( m/\[MyTag\]/../^$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }' ~/myFile.txt
```

the SSH command I'm using is

```
ssh user1@host1 -n " here I'm placing my perl command"
```

I did try to add \ to avoid translating $ sign by the current shell as well as changing the ssh duple quota " to single one and adding \' to the perl command but I'm always getting the error above or unmatched '

I did try below

```
ssh user1@host1 -n "perl -p -i '.backup'  -e ' if ( m/\[MyTag\]/../^$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }' ~/myFile.txt"

ssh user1@host1 -n "perl -p -i '.backup'  -e ' if ( m/\[MyTag\]/../^\$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }' ~/myFile.txt"

ssh user1@host1 -n 'perl -p -i \'.backup\'  -e \' if ( m/\[MyTag\]/../^$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }\' ~/myFile.txt'
```

also with \$ as well as \\$ and more

Comment: OS is Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64

Comment: I'd try double-escaping the `$` as `\\$`, but am not in a position to test it out.

Comment: I did try this as well but didn't work "Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters."

Comment: have you tried `/^\Z/` and/or adding a space before your regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597777/quoting-in-bash-and-perl-in-recursive-ssh-command

Comment: To escape the dollar sign in the first command you need three backslashes...

Comment: Try putting a `-n` as one of your Perl parameters: ` -n:  assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program`. This should set `$_` for your `m/..../` and `s/.../.../` expressions. As long as your Perl script appears in single quotes, you don't have to put a backslash in front of `$`

Comment: Just curious about `m/\[MyTag\]/../^$/`. What is this suppose to mean? Normally `m/.../` should be a single regular expression surrounded by `/`.

Comment: @davidW no that's fine, it's two regular expressions connected with a `..` operator.

Comment: Ah, of course. I thought the OP was using ellipses to show missing information.

Comment: Nothing in your current Perl code would produce this error message.  Can you please post a snippet which actually exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Let the computer take care of the quoting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('user1@host1');
$ssh->system('perl', '-p', '-i', '.backup', '-e', <<PERL_CODE, \'~/myFile.txt');
if (m/\[MyTag\]/ .. m/^$/) {
    s/Item\d+/Item150/;
}
PERL_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape the dollar sign, put three backslashes in front. The following command seems to work for me:

```
ssh user1@host1 -n "perl -p -i '.backup'  -e ' if ( m/\[MyTag\]/../^\\\$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }' ~/myFile.txt"
```

Comment: Hi
 it doesn't work on Linux on Unix it may work

sh user1@host1 -n "perl -p -i '.backup'  -e ' if ( m/\[MyTag\]/../^\\\$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }' ~/myFile.txt"
Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I suppose you mean `ssh` and not `sh`? Does it work without the `-n` switch?

Comment: same happens when running without -n 
however if I replace the perl single ' with double " then it run but Perl doesnt replace the value as it should `ssh user1@host1 -n ' perl -p -e " if ( m/\[MyTag\]/ .. /^\$/ ) { s/Item\d+/Item150/ ; }" ~/myFile'`

Comment: Ok, let's try some simple debugging technique.. Let's see first if you can print a single dollar sign: `ssh user1@host1  "perl -e 'print \"\\\$\n\"'";`

Comment: this doesn't work  ssh user1@host -n "perl -e 'print \"\\\$\n\"'";
Unmatched '.