# how to use openssh to send commands to a CLI service running inside a vm?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, openssh

I'm fairly new to openssh, i am writing a framework to automate a couple of tasks.
I understand that its easy to send commands over ssh to a remote vm to do some things. But i want to send some commands to a CLI-like service that's running inside my remote vm.
To explain it better:

```
[c:\~]$ ssh root@x.x.x.x 
Connecting to x.x.x.x:22...
Connection established.
To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.
[root@vm1 ~]# ssh admin@0
admin@0's password:

admin connected from 127.0.0.1 using ssh on vm1
Your last successful login was at 2021-2-1 19:25:27
Your last successful login was from 127.0.0.1
admin@vm1>
```

This is what i'm doing,
a)I log into my remote machine via ssh.
b)Then i log into the CLI-like service that's running inside my vm.

So what i want to achieve is, i want to run some commands on the CLI on my vm. My perl script presently looks like this. (Note: My perl script is running in a different vm altogether)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;
use IO::Pty;

print "New connection\n";
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("x.x.x.x",user=>'admin', password=>'password', port=>22, timeout=>30);
$ssh->error and die "Could not connect\n". $ssh->error;
my $cmd = $ssh->pipe_out("show alarm");
while(<$cmd>){
    print "$_";
}
close $cmd;
undef $ssh;
```

This is the o/p that i see:

```
root@debian:~# perl automate.pl
New connection
Your last successful login was at 2021-2-1 19:40:20
Your last successful login was from x.x.x.x



^C
root@debian:~#
```

The o/p i'm expecting is for the command "show alarm" but looks like the command is not reaching the CLI of my target machine.
It would be of great help if can get some guidance from y'all.
Thanks.

Comment: See also [Quoting in bash and perl in recursive ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23597777/2173773)

Comment: *"Then I log into the CLI-like service that's running inside my vm"* In your script you do not attempt to do that? Also you are passing username `admin` instead of `root` when you log into the remote machine. Please clarify.

Comment: If i wanted to execute commands on the remote vm itself, i would give `root` but i'm trying to connect to the CLI itself from the script. If i did `ssh admin@x.x.x.x` on the terminal, i will log into the CLI, but when i do it from the script, looks like its connecting because i'm seeing the login messages however its not pushing the `show alarm` command to the CLI.

Comment: This is a FAQ. See the module [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Connecting-to-switches,-routers,-etc.).

Comment: Thank you guys.
I ended writing a bash script to do whatever i was trying to do with perl. It works fine now. I wrote an expect script for authentication with the cli cause somehow Public key authentication does not work on the cli. In any case, in my bash script, i kind of have to open the connection to send a command everything but in perli i would have got the connection object and i could have used the same objects to push as many commands as i want which i think is the biggest limitation of non-object oriented languages.