# Using single quotes inside argument to recursive system bash call

Tags: perl, shell, quoting

I have a Perl script `progA.pl` which needs to run another Perl script `progB.pl` using the `system` command. However, `progB.pl` has been aliased in `~/.bashrc` so I need to ensure that it is run after `~/.bashrc` has been loaded. I can achieve this by using `bash` with the `-lc` option.

For this question, I simplify the problem as much as I think is needed, by considering the following version of `progB.pl`

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dd dump);

say "Received \@ARGV: " . dump @ARGV;
```

and here is `progA.pl`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dd dump);

my $cmd = qq(progB.pl --opt='This option contains '"'"'single'"'"' quotes');
say "cmd = " . dump($cmd);
system( "$cmd" );
say "-----";
system( 'bash -c ' . "$cmd" );
say "-----";
system( 'bash -c ' . "'$cmd'" );
say "-----";
system( "bash -c  \"$cmd\"" );
```

Running

```
$ progA.pl
```

gives output:

```
cmd = "progB.pl --opt='This option contains '\"'\"'single'\"'\"' quotes'"   
Received @ARGV: "--opt=This option contains 'single' quotes"  
-----   
Received @ARGV: ()  
-----   
Received @ARGV: "--opt=This"  
-----   
Received @ARGV: "--opt=This option contains single quotes"
```

We see that this works fine, when `progB.pl` is run directly without using `bash -c`. When I use `bash -c` to run the command, none of the three alternatives are working correctly.

How can I run `progB.pl` with an argument containing single quotes and at the same time using using `bash -c` ?

Comment: One of the reasons that perl was created was as a reaction to the multiple recursive bash calls, and to the quotation hell that you are experiencing. If it is an option, I would recommend rewriting your bash scripts as perl modules...

Comment: @DovGrobgeld Good advice, but I think it is not an option for this case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid this quoting madness at first place but if you insist, you should avoid at least one level of quoting by using `system ARRAY` version.

```
my $cmd = q{progB.pl --opt='This option contains '"'"'single'"'"' quotes'};
system( qw(bash -c), $cmd );
```

It makes it only one level of quoting madness.

```
my $option = q{This option contains 'single' quotes} =~ s/'/'"'"'/gr; # '
my $cmd = qq{progB.pl --opt='$option'};
system( qw(bash -c), $cmd );
```

There you can make some simple helper

```
sub sq ($) { "'" . $_[0] =~ s/'/'"'"'/gr . "'" } # "

my $option = q{This option contains 'single' quotes};
my $cmd = qq{progB.pl --opt=@{[sq $option]}};
system( qw(bash -c), $cmd );
```

Comment: Nice.. so for each level of nesting (with repect to bash), you can add a new call to the `squ` subroutine.. and it should provide the correct amount of quoting needed...

Comment: Yep, but you should try remove as much of them in first place.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I arrived at:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd = qq(print_first_arg.pl --opt='This option contains '"'"'single'"'"' quotes');
$cmd =~ s/'/'"'"'/g;
system( 'bash -c ' . "'$cmd'" );
```

It seems to work, for this test case at least..

This also follows the approach suggested by @ysth in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24869016/2173773