# Running system command under interactive bash shell

Tags: bash, perl

I am trying to run a command that has been aliased in my `~/.bashrc` from Perl using the `system` command. It works well running the command only once, but when I run it twice the second invocation is run as a background job and then suspended (the same as pressing `<CTRL-Z>`) and I have to type `fg` to complete the command. For example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

system ('bash -ic "my_cmd"');
system ('bash -ic "my_cmd"');
```

The second call never completes. The output is `[1]+  Stopped                 a.pl`.

Note:

- The same result is obtained when replacing `my_cmd` with any other command, for example `ls`.
- It seems not to depend of the contents of my `~/.bashrc` file. I tried to remove everything from it, and the problem still persisted.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Perl version 5.18.2.

**Update**

For debugging I reduced my `~/.bashrc` to

```
echo "Entering ~/.bashrc .."
alias my_cmd="ls"
alias
```

and my `~/.bash_profile` to

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    echo "Entering ~/.bash_profile .."
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Now running:

```
system ('bash -lc "my_cmd"');
system ('bash -lc "my_cmd"');
```

gives

```
Entering ~/.bash_profile ..
Entering ~/.bashrc ..
alias my_cmd='ls'
bash: my_cmd: command not found
Entering ~/.bash_profile ..
Entering ~/.bashrc ..
alias my_cmd='ls'
bash: my_cmd: command not found
```

and running

```
system ('bash -ic "my_cmd"');
system ('bash -ic "my_cmd"');
```

gives

```
Entering ~/.bashrc ..
alias my_cmd='ls'
a.pl  p.sh

[1]+  Stopped                 a.pl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using the `-i` switch for an interactive shell, I think you should use the `-l` (or `--login`) switch, which causes bash to act as if it had been invoked as a login shell.

Using the `-l` switch doesn't load `~/.bashrc` by default. According to `man bash`, in a login shell, `/etc/profile/` is loaded, followed by the first file found from  `~/.bash_profile/`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile/`. On my system, I have the following in `~/.bash_profile`, so `~/.bashrc` is loaded:

```
# Source .bashrc
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Now that your `~/.bashrc` is being loaded, you need to enable the expansion of aliases, which is off in a non-interactive shell. To do this, you can add the following line before setting your aliases:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

A process randomly stopping - aside from `ctrl-z` is usually when it needs STDIN, but doesn't have it attached.

Try it with - for example `passwd &`. It'll background and go straight into 'stopped' state. This may well be what's happening with your bash command. `-i` means interactive shell, explicitly, and you're trying to do something noninteractive with it.

That's almost certainly not the best approach, you probably want to do something different. `bash --login` might be closer to what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Fenech's answer worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with a small addition.  At the top of my ~/.bashrc file, I commented out the following section so that if the shell is not interactive (e.g., a login shell), ~/.bashrc is still read.  On some other versions of Linux I don't see this section.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```