# How do you load bash_profile for bash commands run from perl script?

Tags: bash, perl

I wrote  simple command that lets me run the last N commands from terminal history. It looks like this: `$> r 3` which will replay the last 3 commands.

I have the following alias in my bash profile:
`alias r="history -w; runlast $1"`

And then the following simple perl script for the `runlast` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lines = $ARGV[0] || exit;

my @last_commands = split /\n/, 
    `bash -ic 'set -o history; history' | tail -$lines`;

@last_commands = 
    grep { $_ !~ /(^r |^history |^rm )/ } 
    map { local $_ = $_; s/^\s+\d+\s+//; $_ } 
    @last_commands;

foreach my $cmd (@last_commands) {
  system("$cmd");
}
```

This works but my bash profile has aliases and other features (e.g. color output) I want the perl script to have access to. How do I load the bash profile for perl so it runs the bash commands with my bash profile? I read somewhere that if you "source the bash profile" for perl you can get it to work. So I tried adding `source ~/.bash_profile;` to my `r` command alias but that didn't have an effect. I'm not sure if I was doing that correctly, though.

Comment: See also [How to call a function (defined in shell script) in a Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004489/2173773) and [Running system command under interactive bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581085/2173773)

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to use aliases in a script because that means the behaviour can vary depending on where it is run, which is a support nightmare. It is better to use functions instead.

Comment: `$1` in the alias definition doesn't mean what you hope it means. Anyway, the only thing you really need to know about aliases is, use functions instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) forks a process in which it runs a shell, which is non-login and non-interactive; so no initialization is done and you get no aliases. Also note that the shell used is `/bin/sh`, which is generally a link to another shell.  This is often `bash` but not always, so run `bash` explicitly.

To circumvent this you need to source the file with aliases, but as `bash` man page says

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

Thus you need `shopt -s expand_aliases`, as mentioned. But there is another screw: on that same physical line aliases are not yet available; so it won't work like this in a one-liner.

I'd also recommend to put aliases in `.bashrc`, or in a separate file that is sourced.

Solutions

- Add `shopt -s expand_aliases` to your `~/.bashrc`, and *before the aliases are defined* (or the file with them sourced), and run `bash` as a login shell

  ```
  system('/bin/bash', '-cl', 'source ~/.bashrc; command');
  ```

  where `-l` is short for `--login`.

  In my tests the `source ~/.bashrc` wasn't needed; however, the man page says

  > When  bash  is  invoked  as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that  file, it  looks  for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

  and goes on to specify that `~/.bashrc` is read when an interactive shel that is not login runs. So I added explicit sourcing.

  In my tests sourcing `.bashrc` (with `shopt` added) while not running as a login shell didn't work, and I am not sure why.

  This is a little heavy-handed. Also, initialization may be undesirable to run from a script.
- Source `~/.bashrc` and issue `shopt` command, *and then a newline* before the command

  ```
  system('/bin/bash', '-c', 
      'source ~/.bashrc; shopt -s expand_aliases\ncommand');
  ```

  Really. It works.

Finally, is this necessary?  It asks for trouble, and there is probably a better design.

Other comments

- The backticks ([qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)) is [context-aware](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context). If it's used in list context – its return assigned to an array, for example – then the command's output is returned as a list of lines. When you use it as the argument for `split` then it is in the scalar context though, when all output is returned in one string.  Just drop `split`

  ```
  my @last_commands = `bash -ic 'set -o history; history $lines`;
  ```

  where I also use `history N` to get last `N` lines. In this case the newlines stay.
- `history N` returns last `N` lines of history so there is no need to pipe to `last`
- Regex substitution in a `map` can be done without changing the original

  ```
  map { s/^\s+\d+\s+//r } @last_commands;
  ```

  With `/r` modifier the `s///` operator returns the new string, not changing the original. This "non-destructive substitution" has been [available since v5.14](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#Non-destructive-substitution)
- No need to explicitly use `$_` in the last `grep`, and no need for parenthesis in regex

  ```
  grep { not /^r |^history |^rm ?/ } ...
  ```

  or

  ```
  grep { not /^(?:r|history|rm)[ ]?/ } ...
  ```

  where parens are now needed, but as it is only for grouping the `?:` makes it not capture the match.  I use `[ ]` to emphasize that that space is intended; this is not necessary.

  I also added `?` to make space optional since `history` (and `r`?) may have no space.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to have your Perl script just *print* the commands, and make your current interactive shell `eval` the string printed from your history. (I would probably get rid of Perl entirely but that's beside the point here.)

If the commands get evaluated in the current shell, you avoid many contextual problems which would be very hard or even intractable with `system()` or generally anything involving a new process. For example, a subprocess cannot have access to non-exported variables in the current shell. `var="foo", echo "$var"; r 1` is going to be very hard to solve correctly with your current approach. Using the current interactive shell will also naturally and easily solve the problems you were having with trying to get a noninteractive subshell act like an interactive one.

Aliases suck anyway, so let's redefine `r` as a function:

```
r(){
    history -w
    eval $(printlast "$1")
}
```

... where refactoring `runlast` into a different script `printlast` is a trivial additional requirement. Or maybe just turn it into a (much simpler!) shell function:

```
printlast () {
    history "$1" |
    perl -ne 's/^\s*\d+\s+\*?//; print unless m/^(history|rm?)($|\s)'
}
```

With this, you can also get rid of `history -w` from the `r` definition.

Notice how we are using Perl where it is useful; but the main functionality makes sense to keep in the shell when you're dealing with the shell.

Comment: ` eval "$(printlast "$1")"` doesn't seem to work. I modified my perl script to return the commands separated by semicolons. The eval bash command returns `-bash: 2: command not found`

Comment: @StevieD Thanks for the feedback, I didn't have a chance to test the code until now. I removed the quotes around the argument to `eval` (duh) and switched back to Perl for the `history` post-processing for portability and predictability.

Comment: Works now. My bash skills are non-existent and the quoting or not quoting of stuff confuses the hell out of me. I've never tried to learn bash though. Guess it's time as I want to do more to automate things. I don't see any advantage to keeping things in bash as much as possible, though. Perl is great at these kinds of tasks and, I think, much more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: The second paragraph explains in some detail why you *need* to solve this particular problem in Bash. I completely agree that modern scripting languages are much preferred for many things, though I now prefer Python over Perl.

Comment: I get why you need bash to output the result of the commands. I'm just saying I would not try to replace the entire perl script with bash in this case.

Comment: The replacement I wrote which calls `history` in the curent shell avoids a number of complications with that approach, and is obviously much simpler. The shell trivially has access to its current history, while making it visible to a subprocess is contorted and not entirely robust.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the perl one-liner. You changed the sed command you had there.

Comment: Yeah, it was hard to know whether it was failing for you because you have a different `sed` version or because I had a mistake there. It worked for me but refactoring it back to Perl made it entirely portable (because there are not multiple Perl dialects, and Perl is in practice installed everywhere anyway).

Comment: Well, I learned a lot from this answer and the previous. Thanks for your help. Most importantly, I learned it's finally time to bone up on bash. )

Answer (score 1):

You can't source in a Bash script into a Perl script.  The bash_profile has to be sourced in by the shell that executes the command.  When Perl runs `system`, it forks a new shell each time.

You have to source in the bash_profile for each command that you run through `system`:

```
system('source ~/.bash_profile; ' + $cmd);
```

One more thing, `system` invokes a non-interactive shell.  So, your Bash aliases defined in .bash_profile won't work unless you invoke:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

inside that script

Comment: Thanks. Where in the script does the shopt go? In the system call?

Comment: I tried `system('source ~/.bash_profile; shopt -s expand_aliases; ' . $cmd);` but the aliases are not working. I'm probably doing it wrong. I also put shopt in the .bash_profile script.

Comment: The real beef is "don't do that".