# Perl output shell-escaped string

Tags: perl, shell, escaping, quoting

I'm trying to use a perl one-liner to turn print0 output into quoted shell parameters, kind of like the trick that's something like `.. | xargs -0 printf "%q" {}` but I didn't want to require bash (whose printf implements `%p`). I was kind of amazed to, well, *not find* an easy way to do this in perl. For all of perl's quoting mechanisms, there's no way I saw for **producing** quoted strings. Surely I just haven't looked hard enough.

Hopefully the answer isn't a regular expression. Quoting an elaborate regular expression to put into a shell command-line is not my idea of fun (if only a simple perl program could quote it for me, oh back to the same problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll your own quoting for POSIX-like shells fairly simply - no complicated regexes needed (just straightforward string substitution using literals):

```
$ echo "I'm \$HOME. 3\" of rain." | perl -lne "s/'/'\\\''/g; print q{'} . \$_ . q{'}"
'I'\''m $HOME. 3" of rain.'
```

The approach is modeled after AppleScript's `quoted form of` command:

The input string is broken into substrings by `'`, each substring is itself `'`-enclosed, with the original `'` chars. spliced between the substrings as `\'` (an individually quoted `'`).

When passed to the shell, the shell rebuilds these parts into a single, literal string.

This multi-part string-concatenation approach is necessary, because POSIX-like shells categorically do not allow embedding `'` itself inside single-quoted strings (there's not even an escape sequence).

---

Alternatively, you can install a CPAN module such as [ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm).

---

#### Optional background information

While it would be handy for Perl itself to support such a quoting mechanism for piecing together shell commands stored in a single string to pass to `qx//` (`` `...` ``), such a mechanism would have to operate *platform-specifically*.
Notably, quoting rules for Windows are very different from rules for Unix platforms, and except for simple cases shell commands as a whole will be incompatible too.

From inside Perl, you may be able to bypass the need for quoting altogether, by using the *list* forms of [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and [`open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), which allow you to pass the command arguments individually, as-is, but note that this is only an option if your command doesn't use any *shell* features; for a "shell-less" `qx//` (`` `...` ``) alternative, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32161361/45375) of mine, which also covers shell-quoting on *Windows*.

Comment: `s///` isn't regular expressions? Well you've gone all quoted and escaped it already so I can't really complain. Disappointing that there isn't a canonical easy way to do the same thing.

Comment: @smallduck: Fair point; _technically_, I'm using a regex, but _conceptually_ it is straightforward string replacement based on literals - I've clarified.