# Ignore percent sign in batch file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I have a batch file which moves files from one folder to another. The batch file is generated by another process.

Some of the files I need to move have the string "%20" in them:

```
move /y "\\myserver\myfolder\file%20name.txt" "\\myserver\otherfolder"
```

This fails as it tries to find a file with the name:

```
\\myserver\myfolder\file0name.txt
```

Is there any way to ignore `%`? I'm not able to alter the file generated to escape this, such as by doubling percent signs (`%%`), escaping with `/` or `^` (caret), etc.

Comment: You should accept rud3y's answer instead

Comment: As I said, I'm not able to alter the file generated. I get the file with the % sign as: file%20name.txt. I can't add an extra % into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551829/escape-percent-in-bat-file)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should be able to use a caret (^) [to escape a percent sign](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/39047/how-can-i-pass-a-percent-sign--value-to-regexe.html).

<sup>Editor's note: The link is dead now; either way: It is `%` itself that escapes `%`, but only in batch files, not at the command prompt; `^`  *never* escapes `%`, but at the *command prompt* it can be used *indirectly* to prevent variable expansion, in *unquoted* strings only.</sup>

The reason `%2` is disappearing is that the batch file is substituting the second argument passed in, and your seem to not have a second argument.  One way to work around that would be to actually try `foo.bat ^%1 ^%2...` so that when a `%2` is encountered in a command, it is actually substituted with a literal `%2`.

Comment: You can't escape a percent sign with a caret, only with a percent sign

Comment: @mklement0 Technically you can't escape a percent sign on the command line. The only cause why it seems to work is that cmd.exe searches for the variable `username^` in `%username^%`, so you can also use `%user^name%` it has nothing to do with escaping a percent. Btw `foo.bat ^%1 ^%2` is useless at all, as the carets are simply removed after the `%1` and `%2` are expanded. See also [How variables are expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/463115)

Comment: As @jeb points out,  _`^` cannot actually escape `%`_, despite _generally_ acting as the escape character in unquoted strings.
However, you _can_ use `^` to effectively suppress variable expansion by placing it before, after, or inside the variable name, but that _only works on the command line_, not inside batch files.
The rest of the answer provides a clever solution to the OP's very specific problem: needing to deal with an ill-formed, auto-generated batch file; this specificity of the OP's problem is at odds with how generic the title of the question is, which invites confusion.

Comment: @jeb: Again, thanks for the clarification re escaping `%`. The `^` in `^%2` is useless here, but does no harm: the proposed solution works with both `^%2` and `%2`, because - as far as I know - an interactive `cmd.exe` shell never has parameters, and so a reference such as `%2` is retained as is (treated as a literal; by contrast, you'd have to use `%%2` when calling from another _batch file_). Using `%^2` to be safe and explicit is also an option.

Answer (score 63):

You need to use `%%` in this case. Normally using a `^` (caret) would work, but for `%` signs you need to double up.

In the case of `%%1` or `%%i` or `echo.%%~dp1`, because `%` indicates input either from a command or from a variable (when surrounded with `%`; `%variable%`)

To achieve what you need:

```
move /y "\\myserver\myfolder\file%%20name.txt" "\\myserver\otherfolder"
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note that `%%` only works within a batch file and not within the command prompt itself. On the command prompt itself, a caret will escape a percent sign `^%` displays a `%`.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz: Good point about `%%` not working at the command prompt. However, `^` does _not_ escape `%` there - a subtle distinction, but one that matters: 
`^%`  prints just `%`, because `^` placed before _any_ char in an unquoted string is dropped on output - whether that char needs escaping or not.
But, since `^` cannot escape `%`, the "specialness" of `%` is _not_ deactivated by `^` - try `echo ^%CD%` - it's the same as `echo %CD%`. `echo ^%CD^%` works, but only due to `cmd.exe` now thinking that the _variable name_ is `CD^`, and a _undefined_ var. reference is left _as-is_.

Answer (score 35):

<sup>The question's title is very *generic*, which inevitably draws many readers looking for a generic solution.

By contrast, **the OP's problem is *exotic***: needing to deal with an auto-generated batch file that is ill-formed *and cannot be modified*: `%` signs are not properly escaped in it.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907084/45375) provides a clever solution to the *specific* - and exotic - problem, but is bound to create confusion with respect to the *generic* question.</sup>

If we **focus on the *generic* question**:

##### How do you use `%` as a *literal* character in a batch file / on the command line?

- **Inside a *batch file*, always escape `%` as `%%`**, whether in unquoted strings or not; the following yields `My %USERNAME% is jdoe`, for instance:

  ```sh
    echo My %%USERNAME%% is %USERNAME%
    echo "My %%USERNAME%% is %USERNAME%"
  ```
- **On the *command line*** (interactively) - as well as when using the ***shell-invoking functions* of *scripting languages*** - the **behavior fundamentally *differs* from that inside batch files**: technically, **`%` *cannot be escaped there*** and there is **no *single* workaround that works in *all* situations**:

  - **In *unquoted* strings**, you can use the **"`^` name-disrupter" trick**: for simplicity, **place a `^` before every `%` char**, but note that you're not technically *escaping* `%` that way (see below for more); e.g., the following again yields something like `My %USERNAME% is jdoe`:

    ```sh
     echo My ^%USERNAME^% is %USERNAME%
    ```
  - **In *double-quoted* strings, you *cannot* escape `%` at all**, but there are **workarounds**:

    - You can use *unquoted* strings as above, which then requires you to *additionally* `^`-escape all other shell metacharacters, which is cumbersome; these metacharacters are: `<space> & | < > "`
    - Alternatively, *unless* you're invoking a *batch file*, , you can ***individually* double-quote `%` chars** as part of a compound argument (most external programs and scripting engines parse a compound argument such as `"%"USERNAME"%"` as verbatim string `%USERNAME%`):

      ```sh
       some_exe My "%"USERNAME"%" is %USERNAME%
      ```
  - **From *scripting languages***, if you know you're **calling a *binary* executable**, you may be able to **avoid the whole problem by forgoing the *shell*-invoking functions in favor of the "shell-free" variants**, such as [using `execFileSync` instead of `execSync` in Node.js.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33026344/45375)

---

##### Optional background information re *command-line* (interactive) use:

<sup>Tip of the hat to [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) for his help with this section.</sup>

**On the *command line* (interactively), `%` can technically *not be escaped at all***; while `^` is *generally* `cmd.exe`'s escape character, it does *not* apply to `%`.

**As stated, there is *no* solution for *double-quoted* strings, but there are *workarounds* for *unquoted* strings:**

**The reason that "`^` name-disrupter" trick (something like `^%USERNAME^%`) works** is:

- It "disrupts" the *variable name*; that is, in the example above `cmd.exe` looks for a variable named `USERNAME^`, which (hopefully) doesn't exist.
- On the command line - unlike in batch files - references to *undefined* variables are *retained as-is*.

Technically, a *single* `^` inside the variable name - anywhere inside it, as long as it's not next to another `^` - is sufficient, so that `%USERNAME^%`, for instance, would be sufficient, but **I suggest adopting the convention of methodically placing `^` *before each and every* `%` *for simplicity***, because it also works for cases such as `up 20^%`, where the disruption isn't even necessary, but is benign, so you can apply it *methodically*, without having to think about the specifics of the input string.

A `^` before an *opening* `%`, while not necessary, is benign, because `^` escapes the very next character, whether that character needs escaping - or, in this case, *can* be escaped - or not. The net effect is that such `^` instances are ultimately *removed* from *unquoted* strings.

*Largely hypothetical caveat*: `^` is actually a *legal character in variable names* (see jeb's example in the comments); if your variable name *ends with* `^`, simply place the "disruptive" `^` somewhere *else* in the variable name, as long as it's not directly next to another `^` (as that would cause a `^` to appear in the resulting string).
That said, in the (very unlikely) event that your variable has a name such as `^b^`, you're out of luck.

Comment: For me ``"%%"`` worked for a batch file in windows 7 sendto: command ``ffmpeg -i %1 ./image"%%"05d.png`` where in cmd the command would be ...``image%05d.png``.

Comment: @Phann: Re batch file: You don't need the `"..."` around `%%`, and I suggest not using it in general, as not  all target programs may strip the token-internal `"` chars. for you. If a token needs double-quoting for the _other_ characters contained in it, double-quote it _as a whole_.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586963/463115) how to use literal percent signs on the command line, even inside quotes

Comment: Thank you this is such a comprehensive answer. I've been searching for a while and couldn't find my answer until now.

Answer (score 16):

In batch files, the percent sign may be "escaped" by using a double percent sign ( %% ).
That way, a single percent sign will be used within the command line. from http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: And to understand, why a percent sign can only be escaped with a percent sign and not with a caret, you can read at [how cmd.exe parse scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Comment: If part of a command line though you still need a `^` if you are trying to escape a variable, placing the `^` inside the variable name will stop it expanding. Something like `%Variable^Name%` will escape as `%VariableName%` and not be expanded.

Answer (score 3):

How to "escape" inside a batch file withoput modify the file**
The original question is about a generated file, that can't be modified, but contains lines like:

```
move /y "\\myserver\myfolder\file%20name.txt" "\\myserver\otherfolder"
```

That can be partly solved by calling the script with proper arguments (`%1`, `%2`, ...)

```
@echo off

set "per=%%"
call generated_file.bat %%per%%1 %%per%%2 %%per%%3 %%per%%4
```

This simply sets the arguments to:

```
arg1="%1"
arg2="%2"
...
```

**How to add a literal percent sign on the command line**

[mklement0 describes the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/463115), that escaping the percent sign on the command line is tricky, and inside quotes it seems to be impossible.

But as always it can be solved with a little trick.

```
for %Q in ("%") do echo "file%~Q20name.txt"
```

`%Q` contains `"%"` and `%~Q` expands to only `%`, independent of quotes.

Or to avoid the `%~` use

```
for /F %Q in ("%") do echo "file%Q20name.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got a partial solution working.  If you're only looking to transfer files that have the "%20" string in their name and not looking for a broader solution, you can make a second batch file call the first with %%2 as the second parameter.  This way, when your program tries to fetch the second parameter when it hits the %2 in the text name, it will replace the %2 with an escaped %2, leaving the file name unchanged.

Hope this works!

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer, where use of `^%2` as the 2nd parameter is proposed; the only difference is the syntax - `^%2` vs. `%%2`, which is explained by the difference between generating a literal `%` on the command line (the `^` actually has no effect here) vs. inside a batch file.