# is it possible to echo an echo command into a new file?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm trying to use a batch file to create another batch file... it's a file I have to use quite often with a few variables changed each time. I'm running into an issue because in the batch I'm trying to create, it is also using echo to write to a .txt file.

Here is the command:

```
echo echo %date% - %time% >> C:\MOVEit\Logs\FileGrabberLog.txt >> C:\filegrabber_%org%.bat
```

I want to enter the whole string `echo %date% - %time% >> C:\MOVEit\Logs\FileGrabberLog.txt` into C:\filegrabber_%org%.bat.

I can put "" around it but then they appear in the batch I'm trying to create.

Anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You escape `%` with `%%` and other special characters with `^` so this should work;

```
echo echo %%date%% - %%time%% ^>^> C:\MOVEit\Logs\FileGrabberLog.txt >> C:\filegrabber_%org%.bat
```

Comment: You're right about the escape characters, but I think he wants the output to go into `C:\filegrabber_%org%.bat`, so he should not escape the second `>>`.

Comment: true, I'm looking to get all of this: `echo %date% - %time% >> C:\MOVEit\Logs\FileGrabberLog.txt` into C:\filegrabber_%org%.bat

Comment: @user1083755 Glad it worked. You should accept Alex K.'s answer by clicking the big checkmark to the left of his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or to avoid the carets you can use *disappearing quotes*

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  echo !="!echo %%date%% - %%time%% >> C:\MOVEit\Logs\FileGrabberLog.txt
) > C:\filegrabber_%org%.bat
```

Only the percents have to be doubled then.

It works, as the `!="!` is parsed in the special character phase, and it is decided, that the rest of the line will be quoted.

And in the delayed phase the `!="!` will be removed, as the variable with the name `="` does not exist (and it can't be created).

Answer (score 0):

The following answer might be beneficial to your question:

This was posted earlier and the answer was given, similar to what was given here:
[Ignore Percent Sign in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397572/1010904)