# Batch file to not write variables in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will write other files.
This is my file:

```
@echo off
set x=100
echo %x% >> output.txt
```

What this does is create a text file called "output.txt".
In this file it will display "100"

This is not what I want it to, I want the file to contain "%x%" literally.

The reason I am trying to do this is because I would like a batch file to create other complex batch files.
I could use copy or move to move another file containing what I want, but I need this to be a single file.

I would really appreciate some help, but it is understandably really difficult to understand.

Thanks Jason

Comment: I strongly suggest you to change the title of this question to something like "How to write a percent sign in a Batch file". Current title is nonsense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore percent sign in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907057/ignore-percent-sign-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a batch file, double up your percent signs:

```
@echo off
set x=100
echo %%x%% >> output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been trying to do this for ages

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, you can click the check mark next to it to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just set x after you create the file:

```
@echo off
echo %x% >> output.txt
set x=100
```

This should work because you don't *need* to set x that early in the program (at least under those circumstances you don't).

Comment: this may work directly at command line, but not in batch files.

Comment: I don't believe you. If `%x%` is not defined, the batchfile executes `echo  >> output.txt`, which writes `Echo is off.` to the file.

Comment: yes, on command line, `echo %undefinedVariable%` outputs literally `%undefinedVariable%`. You may want to delete or change your answer, before it gets downvoted.