# passing parameters to script from powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I have a script like this:

```
param(
[string]$root,
[string]$bin,
[string]$out,
[string]$zdir
)


echo "args..."
echo "Root: $root", "zdir: $zdir", "out: $out", "bin: $bin"
```

I invoke it like follows:

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -file "C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\zip.ps1" -root "C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\" -zdir "Zip" -out "output.zip" -bin "C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\bin\Debug\"
```

But my output is quite to the contrary:

```
C:\code\misc>powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -file "C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Docu
ments\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\zip.ps1" -root "
C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\Outlo
okCompass\" -zdir "Zip" -out "output.zip" -bin "C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\
Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\bin\Debug\"
args...
Root: C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompas
s\OutlookCompass" -zdir Zip -out output.zip -bin C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Document
s\Visual
zdir:
out: 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\bin\Debug"
bin: Studio
```

Comment: the variable `$root` hold the entire should just hold `"C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\"` but thats not whats output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*: The problem still affects Windows PowerShell, but has been **fixed in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**.

---

[Duncan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107660/duncan) contains the crucial pointer (and helpful background information as well): **`\"` at the end of the parameter values is interpreted as an *escaped* `"`, which causes parameter boundaries to be misinterpreted**.

Your **options** are:

- Use `\\"` instead of `\"` at the end of each parameter value, as Duncan suggests (e.g., `"c:\foo bar\\"`)
- Omit the trailing `\` from the paths altogether (e.g., `"c:\foo bar"` instead of `"c:\foo bar\"`)
- If you want to **avoid having to modify the parameter values**, use the following, *single-quoted* solution (verified on v3).

**Single-quoted solution:**

<sup>This assumes that you're calling this from `cmd.exe`, whether from a batch file or at the command prompt (inside PowerShell, you could just use `& <script> ...`)</sup>

- use *single* quotes instead of double quotes
- use the `-Command` parameter instead of `-File`
- prefix the script path with `&` (escaped with `^` to have `cmd.exe` treat it as a literal)

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command ^& 'C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\zip.ps1' -root 'C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\' -zdir 'Zip' -out 'output.zip' -bin 'C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OutlookCompass\OutlookCompass\bin\Debug\'
```

- This works, because by using `-Command` (and PowerShell's `&` (call) operator to invoke a script whose path has embedded spaces), the rest of the command line can be quoted PowerShell-style with single-quoted strings that aren't subject to interpretation (not even by the C-style argument parsing that underlies PowerShell's own startup command-line parsing, with the exception of embedded `"` chars. - see below).
- The only characters that need escaping with this approach are:

  - Use `''` to embed a literal `'` inside a parameter.
  - Use `\"` to embed a literal `"` inside a parameter.
  - If you need to escape `%` chars. to protect them from interpretation by `cmd.exe` as part of environment-variable references (which you'd have to do irrespective of whether you use single- or double-quoted strings), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375) of mine.
- Note that in order to execute a script in the current directory you must `.\`-prefix the script filename, as you would inside PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are invoking your powershell script from `cmd.exe`, and for many legacy .exe programs the sequence `\"` is used to escape a quote into a parameter. Powershell respects this convention so when you invoke `Powershell.exe` you have to follow this escaping convention.

So:

```
-root "something\" -zdir "Zip" -out "output.zip" -bin "something\"
```

Is a single argument containing two double quotes escaped into the string with `\"`. `cmd` removes the other double quotes, so `Zip` and `output.zip` are strings outside the quotes, but as they don't contain any spaces they don't split the argument.

This should work:

```
-root "something\\" -zdir "Zip" -out "output.zip" -bin "something\\"
```

Doubling the backslashes before the quotes mean a single backslash is passed through and the quote mark loses its special meaning. Don't double any of the other backslashes though as `cmd` only regards the backslash as special when a sequence of one or more of them precede a double quote.

Alternatively leave off the trailing backslashes and insert them where needed in your script.

Or just use `powershell` itself as your main command prompt and ditch `cmd` altogether.

BTW, if you invoke another copy of powershell from inside itself it is recognised as something special and the arguments are encoded in base64 and passed with the `-EncodedCommand` command-line option so in that case there is no need to worry about escaped quotes.

Comment: I am running this within visual studio...so what do you suggest I do now?

Comment: Are you generating the command line from a program? If so you could perhaps use the `-EncodedCommand` command line argument and pass your parameter string base64 encoded.

Comment: @mklement0, yes, I've tried to improve that part of my answer. The weird treatment of `\"` actually comes from Microsoft's C runtime library so it is common to most `.exe` programs, but it is a convention for such executables not an aspect of `cmd.exe` itself.

Comment: Good to know about the implicit use of `-EncodedCommand` when invoking another PowerShell instance from PowerShell - handy stuff. Regarding who does the interpretation: I also suggest revising `*cmd* only regards the backslash as special` - again it is _PowerShell_ (possibly via the C runtime library, as you state). On Windows, interpretation of the command line is really completely up to the _program invoked_ - `cmd.exe` does _not_ break the command line into parameters (arguments) up front the way that _Unix_ shells do.