# Run CMD Code in Powershell with ECHO

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

how can I execute the following example in a PowershellScript?

```
 @echo off
 REM Maintenance Mode on
 "C:\ProgramFiles\vdogServer\VDogMasterService.exe" /at:s /rd:C:\vdServerArchive /maintenance:on
 if ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "versiondog Server wurde nicht ordnungsgemäß in den Wartungsmodus versetzt." >> d:\log.txt
 if ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO "versiondog Server wurde ordnungsgemäß in den Wartungsmodus versetzt." >> d:\log.txt
```

I tried that without success:

```
$command = @'
@echo off
REM Maintenance Mode on
"D:\vdogServer\VdogMasterService.exe" /at:s /rd:E\vdServerArchive /maintenace :on
if ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "NOK" >> d:\MMLOG.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO "OK" >> d:\MMLOG.txt
'@

 Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
```

Im a Beginner in Powershell yet, would be nice if someone has a solution for that, BR

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to put all the batch file code in a batch file and have your powershell script execute the batch file.

Comment: The best solution would be to rewrite the batch code to PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *directly* execute batch-file (`cmd`) commands from PowerShell (which speaks a very different language), but
**you can *pipe* a series of batch-file commands to `cmd`, the (legacy) Windows command processor, but it has *severe limitations*:**

```bash
$commands = @'
@echo off
REM Maintenance Mode on
"D:\vdogServer\VdogMasterService.exe" /at:s /rd:E\vdServerArchive /maintenace :on
if ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "NOK" >> d:\MMLOG.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO "OK" >> d:\MMLOG.txt
'@

# !! THIS MAY OR MAY NOT WORK AS INTENDED, DEPENDING ON THE SPECIFIC COMMANDS.
# Simply sends the commands via stdin.
#  /q suppresses printing the prompt between commands, and
#  /d suppresses autorun entries - see cmd /?
$commands | cmd /q /d
```

**Limitations**:

- **`for` loops and escaped `%` chars. do not work**,
  because, **`cmd.exe` parses commands provided via stdin expecting *interactive* command-line syntax, not *batch-file* syntax**, which - regrettably, and for historical reasons - differ:

  - Batch files must use, e.g., **`%%i`** as the iterator variable, whereas interactively you must use `%i` (just *one* `%`); e.g., providing a statement such as `for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do echo %%i` via stdin is a *quiet no-op*.
  - Batch files allow you to escape `%` signs as `%%` (to use them  as *literals*): for instance, you could use `%%PATH%%` to produce *literal* `%PATH%` on output; on the command line - and when piping via stdin - this does NOT work: you end up with `%<value of variable>%`.

    - For the whole gruesome story, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375).
- With this invocation style, `cmd` will *not* automatically reflect the last command's exit code in its own exit code, and PowerShell's **`$LASTEXITCODE` will therefore NOT reflect failure**. (Contrast this with invoking a *batch file* containing the same commands.)

  - Make sure that the code exits with an explicit `exit` call to properly set the exit code.
- **Character-encoding caveat**: You need to (temporarily) set **`$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding`** so as to ensure that  batch commands that contain non-ASCII characters are encoded the way `cmd.exe` expects (that is, based on the active OEM code page).
- Finally, there is a ***cosmetic* issue**, which, however, **would also affect processing the output *programmatically***:

  - Even with `@echo off` as the first line, `cmd.exe`'s *copyright message* invariably prints first (e.g., `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]...`), followed by one instance of the prompt string (e.g. `C:\>`)
  - Either way, each command's *source-code line* prints before its output.

---

For these reasons, **you're generally better off writing the commands to a *(temporary) batch file* and invoking that**:

Note: You can also use this function to execute the content of a batch file downloaded from the web with `Invoke-WebRequest` / `Invoke-RestMethod`, as requested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73312736/45375).

```bash
function Invoke-AsBatchFile {
 
  param(
    [string] $batchFileContents
  )

  # Determine a unique file path to serve as a temp. batch file.
  $tempBatchFile = "$(Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())).cmd"

  # Write the commands to the batch file.
  # Note: -Encoding OEM assumes that the current console window's
  #       active code page is at its default, the system's active OEM code page.
  $batchFileContents | Set-Content -Encoding OEM -LiteralPath $tempBatchFile

  # Execute the temp. batch file with pass-through arguments, if any.
  # (Reflected in the automatic $args variable.)
  & $tempBatchFile $args

  # Remove the temp. batch file.  
  Remove-Item $tempBatchFile
  # $LASTEXITCODE now contains the temp. batch file's exit code
  # (whereas $? should be ignored).

}
```

Sample invocation:

```bash
$command = @'
@echo off
REM Maintenance Mode on
"D:\vdogServer\VdogMasterService.exe" /at:s /rd:E\vdServerArchive /maintenace :on
if ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "NOK" >> d:\MMLOG.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO "OK" >> d:\MMLOG.txt
'@


Invoke-AsBatchFile $command

if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { Write-Error "Something went wrong." }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited to test exit code per comment:

```
#Maintenance Mode on 
& "C:\ProgramFiles\vdogServer\VDogMasterService.exe" /at:s /rd:C:\vdServerArchive /maintenance:on
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    "versiondog Server wurde ordnungsgemäß in den Wartungsmodus versetzt." | out-file d:\log.txt -append
} else {
    "versiondog Server wurde nicht ordnungsgemäß in den Wartungsmodus versetzt." | out-file d:\log.txt -append
}
```