# How can I download and execute a .bat file in a single powershell command?

Tags: powershell

Is there an equivalent to `iwr https://deno.land/install.ps1 -useb | iex` for `.bat` files? I would like to run `install-bin-windows.bat` from https://yihui.org/tinytex/#installation without manually downloading and executing the file.

This is the error I got when I attempted to pipe the content of the `.bat` file to `iex`

```
PS C:\Users\shara> iwr https://tinytex.yihui.org/install-bin-windows.bat -useb | iex
Invoke-Expression:
Line |
   1 |  iwr https://tinytex.yihui.org/install-bin-windows.bat -useb | iex
     |                                                                ~~~
     | Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
```

Comment: I believe you can just pipe the output directly to cmd.exe //// `Invoke-RestMethod https://tinytex.yihui.org/install-bin-windows.bat | cmd`

Comment: @Daniel, that is tempting, but not robust: most notably, `for` loops and escaped `%` chars. malfunction with this approach, and there are other limitations.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948297/45375) explains that while you technically *can* pipe the content of a batch file directly to `cmd.exe`, the resulting limitations mostly make this impractical.

Thus, unfortunately, a robust solution requires saving the downloaded content to a *temporary batch file* and executing that, as also shown in the linked answer, via the custom 
`Invoke-AsBatchFile` function.