# How To Echo 2 % Symbols Without Shaping It As A Variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm trying to make an enemy attack function, but I have this problem

```
(
echo echo a wild %Enemy% Appears :O
)>Root\Enemies\AttackSystem.bat
```

But It just Replaces it as a variable... How do I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore percent sign in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907057/ignore-percent-sign-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo echo a wild %%Enemy%% Appears :O
```

Normally `^` "escapes" a character like `|` which has a special meaning to `cmd` and signals that it is to be interpreted as a normal character. The escape character for `%` however is `%`.