# How do I escape %% in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I'm echoing out line from a batch file into another file. I know that to escape % you need %% but i can't figure out the escape sequence for %%. The following is what I am trying to accomplish

```
echo something %%stuff > secondFile.txt
```

Resulting in

```
something %%stuff
```

I have tried the following patterns:

- %%%%
- ^%^%
- %%%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore percent sign in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907057/ignore-percent-sign-in-batch-file)

Comment: No, you have not tried `%%%%` in a batch file as this would result in `%%` literally; perhaps you tried it in command prompt directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's different on command line and in a batchfile.

On commandline: `echo some %%stuff`
in a batchfile: `echo some %%%%stuff`