# Can I echo two percent signs to a file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to echo a loop function to another file and I need to echo two percent signs to it

What I have:

```
echo for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do echo %%x > main.bat
echo pause >> main.bat
```

Output:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do echo %x 
pause
```

Comment: Try `%%%%` please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape %% in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977892/how-do-i-escape-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Sorry, just found a decent duplicate, after getting lost in not-quite answering ones.... That is why I answered AND THEN close-voted for dupe.

Comment: duplicates: [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551829/995714), [Ignore percent sign in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907057/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found out that, because of escaping mechanisms, `echo %%` gets you one `%`.
So if you need `%%` then do `echo %%%%`.