# Escaping the and (&) sign in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, escaping, ampersand, quoting

I need to use `\r\n` inside of `ffmpeg --header` parameter. This works in Unix, but not in Windows command prompt. So I was wondering to use `powershell`

```
powershell c:\ffmpeg -headers 'User-Agent: user-agent'"`r`n"'Cookies: my-cookie' ...
```

I understand I have to use `'string'` when special characters are used and

```
"`r`n"
```

as my `\r\n` delimiter.

I have also tested that I can mix them together, like `'this '"is "'text'` to get `this is text`

However if my string (cookie or user-agent) contains `&` character, it fails.

Example: `powershell c:\ffmpeg -headers 'Cookies: param=a=1&b=2; session=123'`

How can I "escape" `&` character in one-liner?

---

These examples (some parts are masked) are accepted by CMD, but they are not working

```
powershell -c "c:\ffplay -user_agent ""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"" -headers ""Cookie: nlqptid=h=676886edeea5bae904b0cf53daec8038.1519940538670&hdnea=exp=1519940598~acl=/*~hmac=C0E019502B060D23AB02BB157FCFFC72404500770A2CE5B00789A84AAEFBD77F&nltid=xxxxxxxxxx&nltdt=0&uid=744826&csid=xxxxxxxxxx; hdntl=exp=1520026938~acl=%2f*~hmac=952689e6de57a2a201ddc1d4c0794962fdc886ea48cf41494a42e787ef923bf9`r`n"" -i ""https://xxxxxxxxxx.net/nlds_vod/xxxxxxxxxx/vod/2018/02/28/cd264e10-dd54-3de2-df90-4c1cac104dcb/v1/stream/cd264e10-dd54-3de2-df90-4c1cac104dcb_1_4500_pc.mp4.m3u8"""
```

or

```
powershell -c "c:\ffplay -headers ""User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0`r`nCookie: nlqptid=h=676886edeea5bae904b0cf53daec8038.1519940538670&hdnea=exp=1519940598~acl=/*~hmac=C0E019502B060D23AB02BB157FCFFC72404500770A2CE5B00789A84AAEFBD77F&nltid=xxxxxxxxxx&nltdt=0&uid=744826&csid=xxxxxxxxxx; hdntl=exp=1520026938~acl=%2f*~hmac=952689e6de57a2a201ddc1d4c0794962fdc886ea48cf41494a42e787ef923bf9`r`n"" -i ""https://xxxxxxxxxx.net/nlds_vod/xxxxxxxxxx/vod/2018/02/28/cd264e10-dd54-3de2-df90-4c1cac104dcb/v1/stream/cd264e10-dd54-3de2-df90-4c1cac104dcb_1_4500_pc.mp4.m3u8"""
```

`ffplay` says

> An input file must be specified

But the input file is specified after `-i` parameter.

What is wrong with this command?

---

*Note that the implementation is a part of the existing batch script, therefore it is required to use a syntax working inside of batch file.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling from `cmd.exe`, things get tricky; here's a simplified example:

```bash
powershell -c " ffmpeg.exe -h \""User-Agent: usra`r`nCookies: parm=a=1&b=2; session=1\"" "
```

In short: **From `cmd.exe` / batch files, to pass what PowerShell's CLI should see as a double-quoted argument *inside an overall `"..."` string passed to `-Command` (`-c`)***<sup>[1]</sup> (which is `powershell.exe`'s *default* parameter):

- ***If possible*, use `\"...\"`**, the ***preferred* form of escaping**, because it works in *both* PowerShell editions and also aligns with how *most* CLIs expect `"` to be escaped; however, it doesn't work in *all* cases when calling from `cmd.exe`, such as the case at hand.
  By contrast, **`\"...\"` is *always* safe to use from *no-shell contexts***, such as Task Scheduler and the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>).
- To **also handle all *edge cases* of calling the PowerShell CLI *from `cmd.exe` / batch files*** - namely when the string to be quoted contains `cmd.exe` *metacharacters* such as `|` or `&` (as in your case) - use the following in lieu of `\"...\"`:

  - When calling ***Windows PowerShell*** ([`powershell.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)): use **`\""...\""`** (sic), as shown above.

    - **Minor caveat**: If *whitespace normalization* (runs of two or more spaces becoming a single space each) is a concern (it rarely is), use **`" ^^^"\"...\""`** (sic) - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997805/45375).
  - When calling ***PowerShell (Core) v6+*** ([`pwsh.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)): use **`""...""`**, which is *fully robust* (prevents both misinterpretation by `cmd.exe` and whitespace normalization).
  - As an aside: As a *general requirement*, `%` chars. must be escaped as `%%` to prevent them from being interpreted as part of a `cmd.exe` variable reference *in batch files*. From the *command prompt*, [things are unfortunately more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375).

---

###### Background information:

- The **command line for *PowerShell* is best passed as a *single*, `"..."`-enclosed string**, via parameter `-c` (short for `-Command`, which in *Windows PowerShell* is the default, but that has changed in PowerShell (Core) v6+, which now defaults to `-File`).
- Since the PowerShell CLI *strips *unescaped* `"` characters during command-line parsing*, *before* interpreting the result as PowerShell code, any **`"` instances to be retained *as part of the command to ultimately execute* must be *escaped*** (note that PowerShell-*internally* `` `" `` is used to escape a `"`; alternatively, in the context of `"..."` strings only, `""` may be used).
- **`\""...\""` (*Windows PowerShell*) and `""...""` (*PowerShell (Core) v6+*) inside an overall `"..."` `-c` argument ensure that `cmd.exe` itself interprets `...` as being inside a double-quoted string, which is what makes these escaping forms *robust***.
- If `\"...\"` were used inside `"..."` from `cmd.exe` (which only recognizes `""` as an escaped `"`), it would in effect see `...` as being *outside* a double-quoted string, which would cause values that contain `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` and `|` to *break the command*. Compare the following invocations from `cmd.exe`:

  ```bash
  # OK - prints verbatim: The king of "Rock  &  Roll"
  C:\>powershell.exe -c " 'The king of \""Rock  &  Roll\""' "
  C:\>pwsh.exe -c " 'The king of ""Rock  &  Roll""' "

  # !! BROKEN - cmd.exe interprets "&" as a metachar.
  C:\>powershell.exe -c " 'The king of \"Rock  &  Roll\"' "
  C:\>pwsh.exe -c " 'The king of \"Rock & Roll\"' "
  ```

  - Note: You *could* fix the use of `\"` by *individually* `^`-escaping such `cmd.exe` characters (e.g., `^&`), but that requires you to analyze the string carefully and determine which specific parts `cmd.exe` sees as unquoted. If you make a mistake, the `^` will be retained as a literal part of the string. The advantage of the `\""` / `""` approach is that you needn't worry about such pitfalls.

---

As an aside: `'this '"is "'text'` does *not* create a single string the way it does in Bash; in PowerShell:

- As a stand-alone *expression*, it causes a *syntax error* (try executing it by itself); you'd have to use `('this ' + "is " + 'text')` or use a *single* quoted string (`'this is text'`).
- As an *argument* passed to a command (program), it is interpreted as *3 distinct* arguments - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375) for an explanation of this - surprising - behavior.

---

<sup>[1] Using *overall* `"..."` quoting around what then becomes a *single* `-Command` argument is conceptually preferable, but not strictly necessary. If overall `"..."` quoting is *not* used, `\"`-escaping of `"` characters that are to be treated as part of the command is the *only* supported form - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375).</sup>