# Powershell: how to replace quoted text from a batch file

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, replace

I have a text file that contains:

```
#define VERSION "0.1.2"
```

I need to replace that version number from a running batch file.

```
set NEW_VERSION="0.2.0"

powershell -Command "(gc BBB.iss) -replace '#define VERSION ', '#define VERSION %NEW_VERSION% ' | Out-File BBB.iss"
```

I know that my match pattern is not correct. I need to select the entire line including the "0.2.0", but I can't figure out how to escape all that because it's all enclosed in double quotes so it runs in a batch file.

I'm guessing that [0-9].[0-9].[0-9] will match the actual old version number, but what about the quotes?

Comment: You do not have to escape here. `[0-9]` matches a digit and `[.]` matches a digit.

Comment: But there are quotes in that line...

Comment: Working replace using LookBehind: `powershell -command "(gc bbb.iss) -replace '(?<=#define VERSION .)\d+\.\d+\.\d+', '%NEW_VERSION%' | Out-File BBB.iss"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what about the quotes?

When calling PowerShell's CLI from `cmd.exe` (a batch file) with `powershell -command "...."`, use `\"` to pass *embedded* `"`.

(This may be surprising, given that PowerShell-*internally* you typically use `` `" `` or `""` inside `"..."`, but it is the safe choice *from the outside*.<sup>[1]</sup>.)

Note:

- While `\"` works robustly on the PowerShell side, it can situationally break *`cmd.exe`'s* parsing. In that case, use `"^""` (sic) with `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell), and `""` with `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell (Core) 7+), inside overall `"..."` quoting. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details.

---

Here's an approach that **matches and replaces everything between `"..."`** after `#define VERSION` :

```
:: Define the new version *without* double quotes
set NEW_VERSION=0.2.0

powershell -Command "(gc BBB.iss) -replace '(?<=#define VERSION\s+\").+?(?=\")', '%NEW_VERSION%' | Set-Content -Encoding ascii BBB.iss"
```

<sup>Note that using `Out-File` (as used in the question) to rewrite the file creates a UTF-16LE ("Unicode") encoded file, which may be undesired; use `Set-Content -Encoding ...` to control the output encoding. The above command uses `Set-Content -Encoding ascii` as an example.

Also note that rewriting an existing file this way (read existing content into memory, write modified content back) bears the slight risk of data loss, if writing the file gets interrupted.</sup>

- `(?<=#define VERSION\s+\")` is a look-*behind* assertion (`(?<=...)`) that matches literal `#define VERSION` followed by at least one space or tab (`\s+`) and a literal `"`

  - Note how the `"` is escaped as `\"`, which - surprisingly - is how you need to escape *literal* `"` chars. when you pass a command to PowerShell from `cmd.exe` (a batch file).<sup>[1]</sup>
- `.+?` then non-greedily (`?`) matches one or more (`+`) characters (`.`)...
- ...until the closing `"` (escaped as `\"`) is found via `(?=\")`, a look-*ahead* assertion
  `((?<=...)`)
- The net effect is that only the characters *between* `"..."` are matched - i.e., the mere version number - which then allows replacing it with *just* `'%NEW_VERSION%'`, the new version number.

---

A **simpler alternative, if all that is needed is to replace the 1st line, without needing to preserve specific information from it**:

```
powershell -nop -Command "@('#define VERSION \"%NEW_VERSION%\"') + (gc BBB.iss | Select -Skip 1) | Set-Content -Encoding ascii BBB.iss"
```

The command simply creates an array (`@(...)`) of output lines from the new 1st line and (`+`) all but the 1st line from the existing file (`gc ... | Select-Object -Skip 1`) and writes that back to the file.

---

<sup>[1] When calling from `cmd.exe`, escaping an embedded `"` as `""` *sometimes* , but not always works (try

`powershell -Command "'Nat ""King"" Cole'"`).

Instead, `\"`-escaping is the safe choice.

`` `" ``, which is the typical PowerShell-*internal* way to escape `"` inside `"..."`, *never* works when calling from `cmd.exe`.</sup>

Comment: Yes it works, partially. Despite me escaping all inner quotes, batch reports an error because it tries to run a powershell command as batch command, since it seems to parse the quotes on the batch interpreter level and they are odd not even in count. Screw you Microsoft. For record, this is the command that causes problems: `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content ACTM.aip) -replace '<ROW\sProperty=\"ProductVersion\"\sValue=\"[^^\"]+', '<ROW Property=\"ProductVersion\" Value=\"%VERSION%' | Set-Content ACTM.aip"` 'Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: The working better solution is this: `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content ACTM.aip) -replace '(?<=<ROW\s+Property=\"ProductVersion\"\s+Value=\")[^^\"]+', '%VERSION%' | Set-Content ACTM.aip"` (basically fixing the quote count by using look-ahead like in your example. The bottom line is, your solution will only work if the quotes total number is even, because of the batch interpreter who tries to be smart and counts quotes. Microsoft did a poor job, I really hate them for wasting my time over and over with this nonsense.

Comment: Yes, @MartinBraun, `cmd.exe`'s parsing is really a shame; I've since learned a way to avoid the `"`-related problems by escaping them as `"^""` (sic) instead of `\"`; with `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell (Core) 7+), `""` works robustly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this sounds really promising, but I fail to not use `\"` in my above comment. Could you please convert it so it would work no matter how many quotes I have in my command? I cannot update PowerShell and need to use core version 6. Is this exclusively for version 7?

Comment: @MartinBraun, try the following (unfortunately, I am _not_ kidding): `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content ACTM.aip) -replace '(?<=<ROW\s+Property="^""ProductVersion"^""\s+Value="^"")[^^"^""]+', '%VERSION%' | Set-Content ACTM.aip"`

Comment: @MartinBraun, btw your use of `powershell.exe` implies that you're using _Windows PowerShell_, whose latest and last version is 5.1 The CLI for PowerShell (Core) - the modern, cross-platform edition that starts with v6 and is now at v7.2.2 - is `pwsh.exe` - as I noted, with `pwsh.exe` you can use `""`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
powershell -Command "(gc BBB.iss) -replace '(?m)^\s*#define VERSION .*$', '#define VERSION %NEW_VERSION% ' | Out-File BBB.iss"
```

If you want double quotes left,

```
powershell -Command "(gc BBB.iss) -replace '(?m)^\s*#define VERSION .*$', '#define VERSION "%NEW_VERSION%"' | Out-File BBB.iss"
```

Comment: You don't need the multiline inline option `(?m)` here, because `gc` (`Get-Content`) outputs an _array_ of lines, on which `-replace` acts _individually_, so `^` by definition only ever refers to the start of each line.
(As an aside: if the input _were_ a multiline string, `\s*` would greedily match whitespace _including newlines_.)
Your 2nd command won't work as intended, because the `"` chars. in the replacement string aren't escaped.

Comment: @mklement0, Thanks for your advice. But, have you tried it? It works and in the single quotes, it seems not need to escape double quote.

Comment: Actually, it does _not_ work: the _closing_ `"` is missing - at least when I run your 2nd command (from a `cmd.exe` command prompt or from a batch file) on Windows 10 with v5.1.16299.251. And the - obscure - reason it _half_ works is because `%NEW_VERSION%`'s value has _embedded_ double quotes, so what PowerShell sees after `cmd.exe`'s expansion is `""0.2.0""`, which - due to the effective doubling of `"` - amounts to escaping of the enclosing `"`, which preserves them in the replacement, but, as stated, only the _opening_ `"`. The safe choice is to escape embedded `"` chars. as  `\"`.

Comment: Your 2nd command - the one that matters, given that the OP is attempting to preserve the double quoting - is still broken, so it's a -1 from me. If you think my diagnosis is incorrect, do tell me. Here's a simplified version of your command to verify that it's broken / to experiment with: Run `set NEW_VERSION="0.2.0"` first, and then `echo #define VERSION "0.1.0" | powershell -nop -command "$input -replace '#define VERSION .*$', '#define VERSION "%NEW_VERSION%"'"`