# Powershell seems to get the wrong number of elements in a param array

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Assume I have (In file `test.ps1`):

```
param (
    [string[]] $one
)
Write-Host $one.Count
```

If I do:

```
powershell -File test.ps1 -one "hello","cat","Dog"
```

I get:

```
1
```

But I expect:

```
3
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-one" is getting passed in as a whole string as the converting happens before calling the method.

You could alternatively call it like the following

```
powershell -Command {.\test.ps1 -one "hello","cat","Dog"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement **[Kevin Smith's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240888/45375)**, which **works *from inside PowerShell only***:

- The only way **to pass an *array* to a PowerShell script via the PowerShell CLI** (`powershell.exe` for *Windows PowerShell*, `pwsh` for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) is to **use `-Commmand` (`-c`)**.

  - By contrast, **`-File` interprets the arguments as *literal values***, and does *not* recognize arrays, variable references (`$foo`), ...; in the case at hand, the script ends up seeing a *single string* with literal contents `hello,cat,Dog` (due to double-quote removal).
- From ***inside* PowerShell**:

  - Use **`-Command` with a *script block*** (`{ ... }`), as shown [in Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240888/45375), which not only simplifies the syntax (just use regular syntax inside the block), but produces type-rich output (not just *strings*, as with other external programs), because the target PowerShell instance uses the CLIXML serialization format to output its results, which the calling session automatically deserializes, the same way that PowerShell remoting / background jobs work (as with the latter, however, the type fidelity of the deserialization is invariably limited; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375)).
  - Note, however, that **from within PowerShell you generally don't need the CLI**, which creates a (costly) *child process*, and can **just invoke a `*.ps1` script file *directly***:

    - `.\test.ps1 -one hello, cat, Dog`
- From ***outside* PowerShell** - typically `cmd.exe` / a batch file - **use `-Command` with a *single, double-quoted string*** containing the PowerShell code to execute, given that **using script blocks isn't supported from the outside**.

  - `powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 -one hello, cat, Dog"`
  - If the array elements *themselves* need quoting, enclose them in `'...'` (for *verbatim* values) or `\"...\"` (i.e. *escaped* `"..."`, for *expandable* strings):

    - `powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 -one 'hello there', cat, \"Dog food\""`
    - Note: In edge cases `\"`-escaping can cause problems when calling from `cmd.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for workarounds.

Note that, with `-Command`, just as with direct invocation inside PowerShell, you ***must* use `.\test.ps1` rather than just `test.ps1`** in order to execute a file by that name *in the current directory*, which is a security feature.

Also note that with your simple argument values, `"..."`-enclosing them is optional, which is why the commands above use just `hello, cat, Dog` instead of `"hello", "cat", "Dog"`.