# How do I include ampersands in a powershell command in a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, google-sheets, quoting

I am trying to download a Google sheet via a batch file. This works:

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID/export?exportFormat=tsv -OutFile output.tsv"
```

When I specify which sheet/tab I want by adding &gid=1234, this breaks:

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID/export?exportFormat=tsv&gid=1234 -OutFile output.tsv"
```

The error is:

> The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved
>   for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to
>   pass it as part of a string.

How do I wrap the ampersand in quotes without breaking the outer quotes for the Command parameter?

Comment: Did you try to enclose the url in single quotes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**The URL embedded inside the `"..."` string passed to `powershell -Command` must be quoted too**, because **an *unquoted* `&` has special meaning** to PowerShell too (though in Windows PowerShell it is currently only reserved for future use; in PowerShell *Core* it can be used post-positionally to run a command as a background job).

The **simplest option is to use embedded `'...'` quoting**, as suggested by [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf), because `'` chars. don't need escaping inside `"..."`. `'...'` strings in PowerShell are *literal* strings, which is fine in this case, given that the URL contains no variable references.

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID/export?exportFormat=tsv&gid=1234' -OutFile output.tsv"
```

**If embedded `"..."` quoting is needed for string interpolation, use `\"`** (sic) to escape the embedded (`"`) chars. (note that *inside* PowerShell, you'd need to use `` `" `` or `""` instead):

```
powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest \"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID/export?exportFormat=tsv&gid=1234\" -OutFile output.tsv
```

Note:

- To avoid problems with *`cmd.exe`*'s up-front parsing, the ***outer* `"..."` were omitted above**, which still works, because PowerShell simply space-joins *multiple* arguments before interpreting the result as PowerShell source code.
- In more complex cases you may prefer the use of outer `"..."`, in which case use of `\"` for *embedded* `"` can *situationally break* (as it would in this case, due to `&`), so more elaborate workarounds are needed: `"^""` (sic) with `powershell.exe`, and `""` with [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the exact same problem recently. If you put a double quote around the URL it won't work. But combination of double quotes and single ones will work:

```
'""ExampleUrlAddress""'
```

With this bypass the Powershell should treat the & and other special characters as string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

My answer: wrap it in double quotation marks like this:
`"&"` so that way, 
 it’ll be passed as part of a string.
If I every try to type something like this:

```
open & close
```

it'll say, "Don't forget to put quotation marks around the & symbol."
I try again, but this time, like this:

```
"open & close"
```

This time, it'll display `open and close` and not give me that error.

Comment: `powershell "open & close"` won't work in a .bat file.