# Stubborn Ampersand with Invoke-Webrequest SQL & Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, escaping, invoke-webrequest

When I run powershell using `invoke-webrequest` on a URL without an ampersand everything works.

But my URL's have ampersands in them. If I surround them by double quotes it works from PowerShell, but not if I am doing it through my SQL Server.

Trying to get the right combination of escape characters is proving to be a pain in the butt. Here's an example of the command:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://example.com/getfile/12345&i=123" -outfile C:\Downloads\test.txt'
```

It is the ampersand on the `&i=123` that is the issue.

If I change the ampersand in the -URI parameter to `"&"` it does not work. If I prefix with the gravy carat (little `` ` `` above tab) it doesn't work. I have also tried to replace it with `%26`.

Racking my brain here for hours. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *embedded* `"..."`-quoting to the URL, which requires escaping as `\"...\"`:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "\"https://example.com/getfile/12345&i=123\"" -outfile C:\Downloads\test.txt'
```

This is necessary, because PowerShell's CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell [Core] v6+), when used with the (implied) `-Command` (`-c`) option<sup>[1]</sup>:

- first removes `"..."` quoting around individual command-line arguments...
- and then joins the stripped arguments with spaces and *then* interprets the resulting string as a PowerShell command line - and at that point quoting around the URL is required, because `&` is a PowerShell metacharacter.

Note:

- Using `\"` to escape embedded `"` chars. inside a `"..."` string in a `-Command` (`-c`) CLI argument works robustly *except when calling from `cmd.exe`*, where the presence of `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` (common in URLs, such as in this case) can *break* the call.
- In that event, use `"^""` (sic) for `powershell.exe` and `""` for `pwsh.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Note that `pwsh` now defaults to `-File`, which expects a *script file*.</sup>

Comment: what about if you were to remove the exec xp_cmdshell and execute the command from another shell or from taskschd?


`pwsh -c {Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "\"https://example.com/getfile/12345&i=123\"" -outfile C:\downloads\test.txt}`

Comment: @Shavelieva, `{ ... }` (script blocks) only work from _inside_ PowerShell (and there you don't need escaping). From the outside, one approach is to use `"..."` around the entire `-c` argument and use `""` to escape any embedded ones: `pwsh -c "Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri ""https://example.com/getfile/12345&i=123"" -outfile C:\downloads\test.txt"`. While using `\"` for escaping works too, it can break _when calling from `cmd.exe`_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).