# Open Powershell from cmd and use filter - problem with escaping?

Tags: powershell

I am starting several powershell instances from a batch script.

With one, I'd like to tail a file and add a timestamp to each line. The command itself works well in powershell directly:

`filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"}; Get-Content .\MyLog.txt -tail 10 -wait | Select-String 'Search term' | timestamp`

But when I use the following command within cmd, I get errors:

`start powershell -Command "filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"}; Get-Content .\MyLog.txt -tail 10 -wait | Select-String 'Search term' | timestamp"; pause`

[Example for an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSuNX.png):

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:18
+ start powershell -Command "filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G):  ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I wonder if I need to escape? Have tried many options but after hours I need some pro help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What "*errors*"?

Comment: I just added an example. As mentioned, I believe it's becaue not not escaping right. I tried so many different versions but none of them worked.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you on?

Comment: you have to escape the double quotes. You're error is also from within PowerShell, not Cmd.exe as the screenshot shows. That specific error refers to a syntactically incorrect annotation. You're calling on `Start-Process` with an argument of `PowerShell.exe`, and then you kind of just left everything else there. PowerShell parses separate words as tokens for that cmdlet, or in this case, parameters. In other words, `Start-Process` does not have a parameter of `-Command` which is why you're seeing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell, there are several ways to include a double-quote character in a string that is between double-quotes (i.e `")`. That's the problem with your command line, when started from a CMD prompt.

To solve your issue, use **`"""`** in the -Command string instead of `"` (except of course for the start and end of your command). See below:

```
start powershell -Command "filter timestamp {"""$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"""}; Get-Content .\MyLog.txt -tail 10 -wait | Select-String 'Search term' | timestamp"; pause
```

Also, instead of adding the pause at the end of your command, you can use the `-NoExit` switch from powershell.exe:

```
start powershell -NoExit -Command "filter timestamp {"""$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"""}; Get-Content .\MyLog.txt -tail 10 -wait | Select-String 'Search term' | timestamp"
```

Comment: Nicely done. Note that while `"""` works (with `powershell.exe`, but not `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell (Core) v6+ CLI), it isn't _fully robust_ when calling from `cmd.exe`. You could more simply use `\"` (in _both_ PowerShell editions), but this too isn't fully robust. A fully robust solution requires `"^""` (sic) for `powershell.exe` and `""` for `pwsh.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).