# I can't run the code when I use powershell.exe -command

Tags: powershell, cmd

Cold you help me with following problem?

How to run the

```
"{0:n10}" -f 21.21
```

code in

```
powershell.exe -command "& {}"
```

argument?

Comment: Are you sure that is complete powershell code? When I run it in a powershell window it doesn't do much

Comment: it doesn't matter, just that the -command also contain  " and the code also contain ". So it maybe does not fit side by side.code is so simple I want to format a single number with {} -f formula to got max 10 decimal digit after the whole number

Comment: `"{0.00} -f "21.21" ` is syntactically invalid, what are you looking to accomplish with that expression ?

Comment: I fixed the code so now it correct

Comment: And what is the different between if i use the -command {} ?

Comment: UniFied Remote control have no powershell prompt only cmd.

Comment: Please edit your question and some larger context on what you are trying to do, particularly around “Unified Remote Control”

Answer (score 3):

- There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly.

  - Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.
- *Unescaped* `"` characters on the command line are *stripped* before the resulting argument(s) following `-Command` (`-c`) are interpreted as PowerShell code. `"` characters that need to be preserved as part of the PowerShell command to execute therefore need *escaping*.

  - From *PowerShell*'s perspective, using `\"` works, in both editions.
  - Additionally, to prevent inadvertent whitespace normalization (folding of multiple spaces into one), the entire command to pass to `-Command` (`-c`) should be passed inside a *single*, `"..."` string overall:

Therefore (note that this assumes calling from *outside* PowerShell):

```
powershell.exe -Command " \"{0:n10}\" -f 21.21"
```

However, when calling from `cmd.exe`, specifically, `\"` escaping *may* break *`cmd.exe`'s syntax*, in which case a different form of escaping of embedded `"` chars. is required - the following works robustly:

- `"^""` (sic) with [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI:

  ```
  powershell.exe -Command " "^""{0:n10}"^"" -f 21.21"
  ```
- `""` with [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI:

  ```
  pwsh.exe -Command " ""{0:n10}"" -f 21.21"
  ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details.