# How to include double quote in Matlab's system() command

Tags: windows, powershell, matlab, cmd, windows-10

I need to pass filename as input to a powershell command which includes spaces. Hence I am hoping to include double quotes.

However, Matlab "eats" all double quotes in the input of `system()` when passing arguments to powershell.

For example, note how the examples below all the the same output.

```matlab
>> system('powershell.exe echo a c','-echo')
a 
c 
ans =
     0
>> system('powershell.exe echo "a c"','-echo')
a 
c 
ans =
     0
>> system('powershell.exe echo ""a c""','-echo')
a 
c 
ans =
     0
>> system(['powershell.exe echo ',char(34),'a c',char(34)],'-echo')
a 
c 
ans =
     0
```

The actual output for `echo "a c"` in powershell is `a c` in a single line. The change of line only occurs without double quotes.

Just for experiment, I also tried `""a c""` and the expected input is the same as change line, a, change line, c. With the return, it seems that any and all double quotes are "eaten" alive by Matlab.

How do I bring the double quotes back when using `system()`?

Comment: Interesting! Could this be related to the invocation of powershell.exe? What happens if you type `powershell.exe echo "a c"` at a cmd.exe prompt?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: The double quotes are tragically eaten as well!

Comment: Maybe they need escaping? `powershell.exe echo \"a c\"`? I don’t have Windows, and have no idea of how its command line works… :(

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Yes, that worked. Thanks for the tip! Would you like to write an answer? It seems calling 'system('powershell.exe ...') in Matlab is the same as calling `powershell.exe ...` in Windows cmd. Somewhere, `"` is filtered from arguments.

Comment: I don’t have Windows, so find it awkward to write this up as an answer. Could you please write the answer? The docs to `system` say a new `cmd.exe` prompt is started for each invocation of `system`, so it makes sense for the two to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *PowerShell* that is eating your double quotes:

- **You're passing a *command* (piece of PowerShell code) to the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter (which is *positionally implied* in your case).
- **`"` characters that should be considered *part of the command*** **must be *escaped as* `\"`** (sic)

  - The reason that *unescaped* `"` don't work is that PowerShell considers them to have syntactic function *on the command line* only - they are simply *stripped* after all arguments have been parsed; the resulting tokens are then joined with spaces, and the resulting string finally interpreted as PowerShell code.
- While using *just* `\"` in your command would fix the problem, it is **advisable to *also* enclose the *entire* command being passed in `"..."`**, because that prevents potentially unwanted *whitespace normalization*.

```
system('powershell.exe " echo \"a c\" "', '-echo')
```

*Caveat*:

- Since MatLab's `system()` function executes the given command line via `cmd.exe` (which is inefficient in your case, since you don't need shell functionality), use of `\"` can *break* the invocation, due to how `cmd.exe`'s parses command lines.
- To **avoid  edge cases when `cmd.exe` is involved**, enclose the overall command in `"...."` and escape pass-through `"` as follows:

  - Use **`"^""`** (sic) when calling [**`powershell.exe`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (the *Windows PowerShell* CLI)
  - Use **`""`** when calling [**`pwsh.exe`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) (the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for more information.