# How to get the Decoded string value using powershell statement from batch script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to decode the encoded password value using powershell, and store the decoded value in a batch  script variable,

I have used the following statement to encode the password in batch script using powershell statement. It is working fine and returning the value to batch script

```bash
@echo off

Set string ="test"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('powershell [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("""string"""^)^)') do set "encoded=%%i"

echo %encoded%
```

Output: `dAB1AHMAdAA=`

I have tried to decode this encoded value using following statement, but it is not returning any value to batch script

```bash
@echo off

Set string = "dAB1AHMAdAA="

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('powershell [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String("""string"""^)^)') do set "decoded=%%i"

echo %decoded%
```

Output: `echo off`

It should return `test` but som how no value is returned

If I manually execute the powershell statement in Windows Command Prompt, it is returning the value `test`.

```bash
powershell [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('dAB1AHMAdAA='))
```

But through batch script it is not returning and it is not giving any error also.
I am beginner in batch script, Please anyone advise what I am doing wrong

Comment: Change ```Set string = "dAB1AHMAdAA="``` to ```Set "string=dAB1AHMAdAA="```, and ```'powershell [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String("""string"""^)^)'``` to ```'powershell "[Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('%string%'))"'```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) has provided an effective solution in a comment on the question, but let me dig deeper:

**tl;dr**

```bash
@echo off

:: No whitespace around "="
:: "..." around BOTH the name and the variable.
set "string=dGVzdA=="

:: Use -NoProfile -Command to call the PowerShell CLI
:: Pass the PowerShell code inside "..."
:: Refer to the value of the variable named string as %string%
:: Enclose %string% in '...'
:: "delims=" is enough - no need for "tokens=* delims="
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  powershell -NoProfile -Command "[Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('%string%'))"
') do set "decoded=%%i"

echo %decoded%
```

---

The ***immediate* fix** is twofold:

- `set string = "dAB1AHMAdAA="` -> `set string="dAB1AHMAdAA"`

  - In a `set` command, `=` *mustn't have whitespace on either side*:

    - If there is, it *becomes part of the variable name and/or value*.
  - Also, `"` chars. on the RHS of `=` become a *literal part of the value*.

    - To avoid that, *omit* the `"` chars. or, to allow `cmd.exe` metacharacters to be used in values, enclose the name, `=`, and the value *as a whole* in `"..."`; e.g.:

      - `set "string=a & b | c"`
  - Also, `"tokens=* delims="` is redundant in that `"delims="` is enough for `for /f` to read each line output by the specified command *into a single variable* (`%%i` in this case).
- `"""string"""` -> `"""%string%"""`

  - That is, you must enclose a `cmd.exe` variable name in `%...%` in order to *expand it to its value*.

---

**Taking a step back:**

- For conceptual clarity, avoid making `"` chars. a literal part of variable values; therefore, based on the above:

  ```bash
  :: Make the value of string verbatim dGVzdA== 
  :: Double-quote later, if needed.
  set "string=dGVzdA=="
  ```
- **When calling [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, or [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, it's best to**:

  - **enclose the PowerShell command(s) being passed to the (default) `-Command` (`-c`) parameter in `"..."` *overall***, which (typically) prevents `cmd.exe` from interpreting metacharacters such as `&` and `>` as *its own*.
  - **precede `-Command` / `-c` with `-NoProfile`** so as to avoid unnecessary overhead and to make the execution environment more predictable.
  - That is, generally use the following idiom:

    - `powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "..."`
- In order **to *nest* strings inside the `"..."` string passed to `-Command`**:

  - **Use `'...'`, if possible**, which avoids escaping headaches.

    - If the string value *itself* contains `'`, *double* such embedded instances; the following example automates this escaping with `cmd.exe`'s substring-substitution syntax, `%var:'=''%`:

      ```bash
      set "var=5 o'clock"

      for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
        powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command " Write-Output '%var:'=''%' "
      ') do echo [%%i]
      ```
  - If you do need to nest a `"..."` string inside the overall `"..."` `-Command` argument - namely if you want to perform *string interpolation* on the PowerShell side - things get tricky - see next section.

---

##### Nesting `"..."` strings inside `powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "..."` in a `for /f` loop:

If you do need to nest a `"..."` string inside the overall `"..."` `-Command` argument - namely if you want to perform string interpolation on the *PowerShell* side (too) - things get tricky:

***Usually*, the best choice is to use `\"...\"`** - it works with the CLIs of both PowerShell editions and also works when calling from *no-shell* contexts such as Task Scheduler and the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>); also, it is effectively *cross-platform*, given that Unix shells such as Bash use `\` as the escape character too:

```bash
set "var=here   and   there"

:: -> [here   and   there]
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command " Write-Output \"%var%\" "  
') do echo [%%i]
```

Note: If a value itself has embedded `"` chars., "escape" them manually as `$([char]34)` (sic; a PowerShell subexpression that yields a literal `"`) or programmatically as `%var:"=$([char]34)%`

However, **given that `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize `\"` as an *escaped* `"` character, this *breaks* if the string value happens to contain `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&`**:

```bash
set "var=here   &   there"

:: !! BREAKS, due to the "&" in the variable value.
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command " Write-Output \"%var:"=`\"%\" "  
') do echo [%%i]
```

- **In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), whose CLI is [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), using `""...""` is a *simple and robust solution***:

```bash
set "var=here   &   there"

:: OK, due to use of ""
:: -> [here   &   there]
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  pwsh.exe -NoProfile -Command " Write-Output ""%var%"" "  
') do echo [%%i]
```

Note: If value itself has embedded `"` chars., escape them manually as `` `"" `` (sic) or programmatically as `` %var:"=`""% ``

- **In *Windows PowerShell*, things are more complicated**:

  - Using **`\""...\""` works safely, but in effect *normalizes whitespace***: that is, runs of *two or more spaces* become a *single space* each.

```bash
set "var=here   &   there"

:: OK, due to use of \"", but whitespace is normalized
:: -> [here & there]
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command " Write-Output \""%var%\"" "  
') do echo [%%i]
```

- **In the rare event that you must *prevent whitespace normalization***, the solution gets ugly:

  - Use **`" ^^^"\"...\""`** (sic)

    - Note: *Outside* `for /f`, the - still obscure - `"^""..."^""` is enough.

```bash
set "var=here   &   there"

:: OK, with whitespace preservation
:: -> [here   &   there]
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command " Write-Output " ^^^"\"%var%\"" "  
') do echo [%%i]
```

Note: In both cases, if a (variable) value itself has embedded `"` chars., "escape" them:

- manually as `$([char]34)` (sic; a PowerShell subexpression that yields a literal `"`)
- programmatically as `%var:"=$([char]34)%`