# Execution of a complex instruction through a chain of CMD and PowerShell terminal prompts

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have recently been struggling to make a set of instructions work as a one-liner. What I want to achieve is to run a special CMD instruction with elevated privileges, but starting from an unprivileged CMD. I have discovered that what I want to do is achievable by leveraging PowerShell as middleman, and I successfully created some one-liners that work, but I cannot wrap my head around a more complex scenario. This is the flow of programs I am planning to use:

CMD (unprivileged) -> PowerShell (unprivileged, triggering admin privileges) -> Either CMD or PowerShell (now with admin rights) -> execution of the desired instruction (that needs admin rights)

I must start from an unprivileged CMD. I planned to launch a PS session from there because I found a nice "trick" (i.e., using `-Verb RunAs` at the end of the command) that lets me switch to an admin CMD/PS session by just pressing "Yes" in the Windows UAC GUI.

This is the final command I must run in an admin CMD/PS session:

```
tbcon -run:"a2lmerger --optionsfile _gen\swb\module\asap2\opt\a2lmerger_internal.opt"
```

Furthermore, this command must also be executed from a specific folder.
I can confirm that, by itself, this command works fine.

I have proceeded step-by-step, and I can assure that this next command works when launched from PS:

```
cmd \"/k cd C:\MY\PATH\WITHOUT\SPACES && tbcon -run:"a2lmerger --optionsfile _gen\swb\module\asap2\opt\a2lmerger_internal.opt"\"
```

Thus, I tried to implement the full solution, launching it from an unprivileged CMD:

```
powershell.exe -Command Start-Process cmd \"/k cd C:\MY\PATH\WITHOUT\SPACES && tbcon -run:"a2lmerger --optionsfile _gen\swb\module\asap2\opt\a2lmerger_internal.opt" && exit\" -Verb RunAs
```

But this fails, as `tbcon` does not receive the argument correctly, and indeed reports me that:

```
[tbcon] ERROR - Invalid argument: '--optionsfile'.
```

I suspect this is because CMD messes up with the space between `a2lmerger` and `--opstionsfile` (and eventually the one between `--optionsfile` and `_gen[...]`), but I spent a lot of time trying to fix this without luck.

Additionaly, it would also be nice to be able to substitute `C:\MY\PATH\WITHOUT\SPACES` with a path that also features spaces, but that would be a bonus.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `"` chars. that you need to preserve as part of command you pass to the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-Command` parameter must be escaped as `\"` (otherwise, the initial command-line parsing will remove them).

- While you're already doing that for the nested `cmd` command line *overall*, the embedded `"` chars surrounding the `-run:` option value *lack* that kind of escaping.
- Escaping them as `\"` isn't *enough* however, given that they need to be interpreted as `"` inside a *PowerShell* string literal, where `"` must be escaped as `` `" ``. You must therefore *combine* these escaping mechanisms, in the right order, namely: `` `\" ``

  - The same applies to enclosing the `cd` argument in `"..."`

Therefore:

```bash
powershell.exe -Command Start-Process cmd \"/k cd `\"C:\MY\PATH\WITH SOME\SPACES`\" && tbcon -run:`\"a2lmerger --optionsfile _gen\swb\module\asap2\opt\a2lmerger_internal.opt`\" && exit\" -Verb RunAs
```

---

**Caveat re *edge cases***:

**`cmd.exe` itself has no concept of *escaped* `"` chars.**; that is, even the `"` in `\"` is considered to start or end a double-quoted string, an *nesting* `\"...\"` therefore creates substrings that `cmd.exe` considers *unquoted*, causing characters such as `&` to be interpreted as *`cmd.exe`* metacharacters, up front, which **can break the command**.
This pitfall applies to *any* command run from `cmd.exe`, not just when calling PowerShell; here's a `cmd.exe`-only example:

```bash
:: From cmd.exe.
:: BREAKS, because the 2nd & is considered UNQUOTED causing
:: interpretation as the statement-sequencing operator.
:: Prints "A & \"B, then looks for a command named C\" D"
echo "A & \"B & C\" D"
```

**Workarounds:**

- ***Manual, situational* workaround**: ***Selectively `^`-escape*** such characters, but that **requires specific awareness of which substrings `cmd.exe` considers unquoted**, which is cumbersome and nontrivial.

  ```bash
  :: From cmd.exe.
  :: OK, due to ^-escaping of the 2nd &
  :: Prints "A & \"B & C\" D"
  echo "A & \"B ^& C\" D"
  ```
- ***Methodical* workarounds**:

  - ***If supported by the target CLI*, use `""` in lieu of `\"`**  as an escaped `"` *inside `"..."` strings*, which fundamentally *avoids* the problem (`cmd.exe`, which doesn't recognize `""` as special either, then in effect sees a concatenation of `"..."` strings, and therefore everything in them as quoted).
    CLIs created with Microsoft's compilers typically *do* accept `""` (*interchangeably* with `\"`), which includes [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI, but - unfortunately - *not* [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI (see next point).
    When calling `pwsh.exe`, enclose a `-Command` argument in `"..."` overall, and use `""` for embedded `"`:

    ```bash
    :: From cmd.exe.
    :: OK, due to "..." enclosure and
    :: escaping of embedded " as "" (if you tried to use \", this would break)
    :: Prints "A & B"
    pwsh.exe -Command " Write-Output ""A & B"" "
    ```
  - **For `powershell.exe`**, the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, the workaround is more cumbersome, unfortunately; **use `"^""`** (sic) inside a `-Command` argument enclosed in `"..."` overall:

    ```bash
    :: From cmd.exe.
    :: OK, due to overall "..." enclosure and
    :: escaping of embedded " as "^"" (sic)
    :: Prints "A & B"
    powershell.exe -Command " Write-Output "^""A & B"^"" "
    ```

    - Unfortunately, this technique **doesn't work *inside `for /f` loops***, necessitating more complex workarounds, discussed in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997805/45375).

Comment: This is just awesome, much more than I expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it; my pleasure, @Jetboy. It's tricky business, and having conceptual clarity helps. There are many answers that cover various aspects of the problem, so I thought I'd try a comprehensive overview.

Comment: I think you made an excellent job; it's not the first time I am asking something online, and while I am always trying to put the effort to first solve the problem by myself and then to at least detail precisely my issue to the web, I rarely get such a positive feedback with the answers I receive.