# powershell oneliner inside of batch loop

Tags: powershell, batch-file, syntax, escaping, quoting

I have following loop:

```batch-file
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=- " %%a in ('
 powershell.exe -Command "Get-EventLog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Newest 1 -LogName System -EntryType Error -Source Tcpip | ForEach-Object { \"$(Get-Date $_.TimeGenerated) - $($_.ReplacementStrings -join '#')\" }; Write-output ^$error[0]"
 ') do (
    echo %%a %%b %%c
)
```

But got this error message:

```
- was unexpected at this time.
```

On the command line, the powershell command works fine.

I have tried to escape dashes and semicolons, but have had no luck.

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: It appears to me as if your nested closing parentheses are the culprit. ```$_.TimeGenerated^) - $($_.ReplacementStrings -join '#'^)```. Although I'm not quite sure why your using a for loop as opposed to getting powershell to output only what you want in the first place.

Comment: This code is a part of larger batch script, I am putting powershell output into a variables there. This simplifycated example is only for demostration purpose. Anyway, excaping closing parenthesis work!

Comment: This is the _simpler_ way I would do it: `powershell.exe Get-EventLog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Newest 1 -LogName System -EntryType Error -Source Tcpip ^| ForEach-Object { \"$(Get-Date $_.TimeGenerated) - $($_.ReplacementStrings -join '#')\" }; Write-output ^^$error[0]` For simple PS code you don't need the `-Command` cmdlet, just insert the PS code with no quotes. This means that you need to "^escape" the harm characters for cmd.exe like the `^|` pipe and the `^^` caret itself, but in this case the `)` right parens don't needs `^)`escape because they _are_ enclosed in quotes!

Comment: @Aacini (I originally misread your comment): Indeed, by removing the outer `"..."` `cmd.exe` then sees the `)` as quoted, due to the ``\"...\"`` enclosure (but any `)` _outside_ it would again have to be `^`-escaped). Ultimately, there's no way around needing to know which parts `cmd.exe` sees as quoted, and which not. An aside re the `-Command` PowerShell CLI _parameter_: It is indeed not required in _Windows PowerShell_ (`powershell.exe`), where `-Command` is the default, but it is now required in Powershell (Core) (`pwshe.exe`), where `-File` is now the default.

Comment: You could always use powershell instead.

Comment: Powershell is much slower then window shell script

Comment: @Aacini, I spoke too soon: ``powershell "...\""...\""..."`` _is_ a way to not have to worry about `^`-escaping any `cmd.exe` metacharacters ever. (``pwsh -Command "...""...""..."`` for PowerShell 7+; I misspelled the executable name in my previous comment: it is `pwsh.exe`, not `pwshe.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

**The `)` characters were the problem**, as [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) points out: Because `cmd.exe` sees what is inside the `\"...\"` string embedded in your overall `"..."` string as *unquoted*,<sup>[1]</sup> you would have to `^`-escape all `cmd.exe` metacharacters there, which in this case - due to the command executing inside a `for /f` loop - *additionally* means all `)` instances:<sup>[2]</sup>

**Use `\""...\""` in lieu of `\"...\"` for your embedded PowerShell string-literal**, *inside the overall `"..."` enclosure* (whose use is advisable - see the next section) - this makes `cmd.exe` see the content of the embedded string as *quoted* and therefore *generally* **avoids the need for metacharacter-individual `^`-escaping**.

```bash
:: Note the use of \""...\"" inside the overall "..." -Command argument.
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=- " %%a in ('
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-EventLog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Newest 1 -LogName System -EntryType Error -Source Tcpip | ForEach-Object { \""$($_.TimeGenerated) - $($_.ReplacementStrings -join '#')\"" }; \""$($error[0])\"""
') do (
  echo %%a %%b %%c
)
```

Note:

- If you were to use **[`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) CLI*** rather than [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, **use `""...""`** rather than `\""...""`, inside overall `"..."` , which is *fully robust* (but doesn't work in Windows PowerShell).
- The only - largely hypothetical - concern with embedded `\""...\""` with `powershell.exe` (which equally applies to embedded `\"...\"` is that *whitespace normalization* could occur.<sup>[3]</sup>

A few changes were made to your original command as well:

- `-NoProfile` was added to suppress [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) loading, which makes for a more predictable execution environment and can speed up the command.
- The redundant `Get-Date` was removed from `Get-Date $_.TimeGenerated`
- `Write-Output ^$error[0]` was replaced with `\""$($error[0])\""` (the escaped equivalent of `"$($error[0])"`, utilizing implicit output) to print the error message only, without the stray `^`, which isn't necessary and gets *included in the output* (it is for that reason that it caused *implicit stringification* of the error-record *object* stored in `$error[0]`, so that `^` followed by the error *message text* only was output).
  (It is tempting to try the syntactically simpler `$error[0].ToString()`, but that would *fail* if no errors had occurred, because attempting to call a method on `$null` causes an error).

---

###### Optional reading: Guidance on whether to enclose the PowerShell commands in `"..."` *overall* or not and how to escape embedded (pass-through) `"` chars.:

The PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) allows you to pass commands to execute either as a *single* argument - which on Windows requires *overall enclosure in `"..."`* - or as *multiple* arguments that are later joined together with a single space as the separator to form a single string that is then interpreted as PowerShell code.

- To `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell), `-Command` (`-c`) is the *default* parameter, so you technically do not need to specify it - all arguments following the first non-CLI parameter, if any, are considered the `-Command` argument(s).
- To `pwsh.exe` / `pwsh` (PowerShell (Core) 7+), `-File` is the default parameter, so in order to pass commands you *must* use `-Command` (`-c`).
- Note: It follows that, *without overall `"..."` enclosure*, *embedded* string literals (from PowerShell's perspective) - whether embedded with `'...'` or with `\"...\"` - are subject to *whitespace normalization*.<sup>[3]</sup>

  - While, *without* overall `"..."` enclosure, `\""...\""` prevents this normalization, with both CLIs, when calling from `cmd.exe` `...` is again considered *unquoted*, necessitating character-individual `^`-escaping of `cmd.exe` metacharacters.

To PowerShell, any *unescaped* `"` characters - whether around the PowerShell commands overall, or around individual arguments - are considered to have purely syntactical function *on the command line*, and are  *stripped* during PowerShell's initial command-line parsing. `"` chars. that should be retained *as part of the PowerShell command(s) to execute* must be *escaped*, but what forms of escaping are accepted depends on whether overall `"..."` enclosure is present:

- `\"` *always* works, in both PowerShell editions, *from PowerShell's perspective*.

  - It works robustly if you call from a *no-shell* environment, such as Task Scheduler or the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>), but outside overall `"..."` enclosure is again subject to whitespace normalization.
- *Only* inside overall `"..."` enclosure (or *individually* `"..."`-enclosed arguments):

  - `"""` works with `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell)
  - `""` works with `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell (Core) 7+)
  - Both forms avoid whitespace normalization.

The implications for calling *from `cmd.exe` (batch files)*:

- If you're calling `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell (Core) 7+):

  - Use overall `"..."` enclosure and `""...""` for embedded strings, for a *fully robust solution*.
- If you're calling `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell):

  - Use overall `"..."` enclosure  and `\""...\""` for embedded strings, because both `\"` and `"""` can run afoul of `cmd.exe`'s parsing, as in the case at hand and as explained in footnote [1] (for `\"`, but it applies analogously to `"""`).
  - This makes the embedded string subject to whitespace normalization, which is rarely a problem, however; see footnote [3].
- With both CLIs, if you *omit* an overall `"..."` enclosure, any `cmd.exe` metacharacters (outside *embedded* double-quoted string literals, if `cmd.exe` happens to see them as quoted too) require character-individual `^`-escaping; a simple example:

  ```bash
  :: Due to no overall "..." enclosure, | must be ^-escaped.
  powershell.exe -Command 1..3 ^| ForEach-Object { \"number|$_\" }
  ```

  - Note that it is use of `\"..."\` for the embedded PowerShell string literal that prevents `...` from being seen as *unquoted* by `cmd.exe`.
  - Contrast this with a solution *with* overall `"..."` enclosure, in combination with using `\""...""\` for the embedded string literal, in which case *no* `^`-escaping is needed:

    ```bash
     :: Due to "..." overall and embedded \"...\", no ^-escaping needed.
     powershell.exe -Command " 1..3 | ForEach-Object { \""number^|$_\"" } "
    ```

---

<sup>[1] `cmd.exe` has no concept of *escaped* `"` characters, so that `"` and `\"` are equally seen as quoting characters with *syntactic* function. Thus, `cmd.exe` sees something like `" \"A|B\" "` as *three* tokens: double-quoted token `" \"`, followed by *unquoted* `A|B\`, followed by double-quoted `" "`. The `|` in the unquoted part is then considered the usual pipe operator, and breaks a command using such a string - unless `|` is `^`-escaped.

Try `echo " \"A|B\" "` vs. `echo " \"A^|B\" "`</sup>

<sup>[2] You wouldn't expect `)` characters to be to be a problem, given the overall `('...')` enclosure, but that is just one of `cmd.exe`'s many parsing "quirks".
A minimal example:

`for /f %%a in (' echo (hi) ') do echo %%a` *breaks*,

`for /f %%a in (' echo (hi^) ') do echo %%a` is sufficient,

`for /f %%a in (' echo ^(hi^) ') do echo %%a` works too - escaping of ( as well, but not strictly needed</sup>

<sup>[3] This means that if runs of *multiple* spaces (whitespace characters) are embedded in what are string literals from *PowerShell's perspective* - whether embedded with `'...'` or with `\""...\""` or `\"...\"` - they become a *single space* each, due to how PowerShell's parsing of the process command line partitions it into separate arguments that are later joined with a single space to form the PowerShell code to execute.

A minimal example:

`powershell -nop -c " 'I watched the \""King      &     I\""' "` prints verbatim `I watched the "King & I"`, i.e. the runs of multiple spaces were folded into one each.

By contrast, `pwsh.exe`'s support for embedded `""` does *not* suffer this problem, so the following preserves the original whitespace:

`pwsh -nop -c " 'I watched the ""King      &     I""' "`

In the (rare) cases where this normalization must be avoided with `powershell.exe`, you can use `"^""` (sic) *outside* `for /f` loops, and an even uglier workaround *inside* `for /f` loops, detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997805/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are starting Powershell.  Just run `powershell -help` on a CMD window.  Under examples you will find the line `PowerShell -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName security}"`.  This is what you are looking for.

But there are some other points I can't understand.

1. The subtraction of `($_.ReplacementStrings -join '#')` from `(Get-Date $_.TimeGenerated)` can't work, because they have incompatible date types.  Just enter this in a Powershell window ...
   `((Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 1).ReplacementStrings -join '#').GetType().FullName`
   => `System.String`
   `(Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 1).TimeGenerated.GetType().FullName`
   => `System.DateTime`
2. The part `(Get-Date $_.TimeGenerated)` doesn't make sense, because `($_.TimeGenerated)` is already `System.DateTime`
3. The return value `$error[0]` is a very complex data type which isn't catch able by `%%a %%b %%c`.  Just enter `Some rubbish to get an error` and then `$error[0]` into a Powershell window.  And then try `$error[0] | ConvertTo-Json` to get an idea of the complexity of this object.
4. Why using `Write-Output`?  I suggest `return` because it's made for write something to StdOut, also when Powershell.exe has to return something.  Write-Output is use able inside Powershell, but to write to StdOut by finishing the Powershell process?  I'm not sure because I didn't try it out.

Finally a little simplified example which is working fine on my Windows 10 with Powershell 5.1.  Caution, the delimiter of the for loop has been modified to "#".

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ('
    powershell.exe  -NoProfile -NoLogo  -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName "System" -Newest 1 -InstanceId  7001 -Source "Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon" | ForEach-Object { $OutValue = (($PSitem.Source) -replace '-', '#')}; return $OutValue }"
') do (
    echo A: %%a
    echo B: %%b
    echo C: %%c
)
```

Please excuse my lousy English.

Comment: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Re 1.: There is no _subtraction_, only incidental use of the `-` character inside an embedded _expandable_ string (`\"...\"`). Re 2.: true. Re 3: `Write-output ^$error[0]` somewhat accidentally _stringifies_ the error object stored in `$error[0]`, and the only anticipated error string `'No matches found'`, happens to work with `echo %%a %%b %%c`. Re 4. True in general, but the alternative to not using `Write-Output` isn't to to use `return` (whose primary purpose is _flow control_, not to produce _output_), it is to use _implicit output_.

Comment: In short: You're misinterpreting the OP's intent, and you're offering incidental incidental advice, some of which is misguided.