# Pass argument(file-path) that contains spaces to the Powershell command inside Batch file that itself resides at path with spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments, powershell-5.0

I have following lines in my Batch script which in turn calls Powershell command to self-elevate the batch file as Admin.

```
@echo off && setlocal
if not "%1"=="admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' admin & pause & exit /b)
....
....
```

But the Batch file path itself and as result the `'%0'` contains spaces in the `%USERNAME%`(Vivek Shah) especially, and that's why when invoking this script, it throws error:

```
The term 'C:\Users\Vivek' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
```

How do I handle spaces in `'%0'` and make this script working perfectly ??

Already tried `'%~0'` & `'"%0"'` but both apparently don't work.

Comment: Have you tried `' "%0" '` (ie. enclose `%0` in `"` quotes?

Comment: Yes @Magoo tried that too, still same error.

Comment: OK - tried `%~s0` to use the short name (assuming you have short-name generation enabled) ?

Comment: That did work like charm, thank you @Magoo. You wanna re-brand this as a working answer ? You can also mention that in answer, what are other options if short-name generation is not enabled, or how to enable it, if there aren't any other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `%~f0` to refer to the running batch file's *full path*.

  - Run `cmd /c call /?` for an explanation of the syntax.
- To ensure that this path is passed as-is to PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) (whose built-in aliases are `start` and `saps`), enclose it in `\"..."\` (the `\`-escaping is necessary in order for the (implied) `-Command` argument passed to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, to pass the `"` characters through as part of the command to execute).<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
@echo off && setlocal

if not "%1"=="admin" (powershell start -verb runas \"%~f0\" admin & pause & exit /b)
```

---

<sup>[1] Note: Without enclosing the implied `-Command` argument in `"..."` overall means that the value of `~%f0` is subject to *whitespace normalization*, meaning that runs of *multiple* whitespace characters are folded into a *single space* each. However, that is rarely a problem in practice. Just adding an overall `"..."` enclosure (`powershell "start ..." & pause & exit /b`) is *not* necessarily enough, unfortunately, because it requires individually `^`-escaping any `cmd.exe` metacharacters inside `\"...\"`. In the rare event that whitespace normalization is a problem, with `powershell.exe` you can use `"^""..."^""` (sic) inside overall `"..."`, but only *outside `for /f` loops* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997805/45375). Fortunately, in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), whose CLI is [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the robust solution is simpler: both outside and inside `for /f`, use overall `"..."` enclosure with embedded `""...""` quoting.</sup>