# Base64 Decode in .bat file using powershell [System.Convert]::FromBase64String not working for all Base64 encoded texts

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, base64

I have to create a .bat file to decode base64 encoded text received via CMD line argument. I created one but its decoding encoded text `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh` and not decoding text `aGVsbG93b3JsZA==`.

Please find below the bat file I am using for testing this.

```batch-file
echo off
set x=aGVsbG93b3JsZA==
echo Base64 Encoded: %x%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell " [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(\"%x%\"))"') do (
  set decodedStr=%%a
)
echo Base64 decoded String : %decodedStr%
set x=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
echo Base64 Encoded: %x%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell " [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(\"%x%\"))"') do (
  set decodedStr=%%a
)
echo Base64 decoded String : %decodedStr%
pause
```

Adding result, no errors. The decoded string is empty for first one

```
Base64 Encoded: aGVsbG93b3JsZA==
Base64 decoded String : 
Base64 Encoded: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
Base64 decoded String : Hello World!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please share a solution to decode the base64 encoded string in bat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping wrong.

use this for both:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'powershell -NoProfile "[system.text.encoding]::UTF8.GetString([system.convert]::frombase64string('%x%'))"'
) do ( 
    set decodedStr=%%a 
)
```

I also added the -NoProfile so it should make it run a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- You're seeing a ***bug* in `cmd.exe`'s [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)** loop command.
- A simple workaround is to **refer to the `%x%` variable via `$env:x`** in the PowerShell command instead of relying on the up-front string interpolation, which causes the problem here.
  This approach is **generally preferable** in order **to avoid headaches with embedded quoting** (see next section).

The fix, applied to a streamlined version of your code:

```bash
@echo off & setlocal

set "x=aGVsbG93b3JsZA=="
echo Base64-encoded: %x%

:: Note the $env:x to refer to the value of %x%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
  powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($env:x))"
') do set "decodedStr=%%a"

:: -> "Base64-decoded string: helloworld"
echo Base64-decoded string: %decodedStr%
```

---

###### Background information:

- The bug is that **`for` inappropriately replaces runs of `=` characters with a *single space each* in *unquoted* arguments** passed to the enclosed command - something that doesn't happen in *direct* invocation.

  - That is, it inappropriately parses the argument *as if it had been passed to a batch file*, where `=` serves as an alternative argument separator (e.g., `foo.cmd foo=bar` is equivalent to `foo.cmd foo bar`)
  - The reason `cmd.exe` sees the expanded value of `%x%` as *unquoted* in  `"...\"%x%\"..."` is that it doesn't recognize `\"` as an *escaped* `"` character, so that it sees *three* strings: `"...\"`, followed by *unquoted* `%x%`, followed by `\"..."`.
  - The following test command demonstrates the problem - it shows that string value `ab=c====de` turns into `ab c de` by the time PowerShell sees it:

    ```bash
    set "var=ab=c====de"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -nop "<# \"%var%\" #>; [Environment]::CommandLine"') do echo %%a
    ```
- **PowerShell indirectly contributed to the problem** in that it made diagnosis of the problem more difficult:

  - It **inappropriately send its *error* output to *stdout*** by default, and since *Windows PowerShell*'s error messages are *multiline* by default<sup>[1]</sup> and *end in an empty line*, the `set` command captured that empty line only.
  - See [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989) for a discussion. Unfortunately, in order to preserve backward compatibility the behavior cannot be changed.

    - However, a caller can use a `2>` redirection to force error message to be routed though *stderr*.
  - [GitHub issue #8072](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8072) is a proposal to provide a new, additional CLI that fixes this and other problems, most notably that PowerShell loads its profiles even when invoked with commands or script files to execute; unfortunately, the discussion around it has stalled.

---

###### Guidance on passing `cmd.exe` variable values (that need quoting) to PowerShell `-Command` (`-c`) CLI calls:

Note:

- Techniques are listed in ascending order of preference (best last).
- `-Command` (`-c`) is the *default* parameter for `powershell.exe`, whereas it is `-File` (`-f`) for `pwsh`; in other words: in order to pass *commands* to `pwsh` (as opposed to the path of a *script file*), *explicit* use of `-Command` (`-c`) is needed.
- It is assumed that the `-Command` argument is passed *inside overall `"..."` quoting*, so as to protect its content from possibly unwanted interpretation by `cmd.exe` (with the exception of the usually desired expansion of `%VAR%`-style variable references).

**Techniques:**

- Using **`"..."` quoting**, which therefore needs *escaping*:

  - Note:

    - On the PowerShell side, the content of [expandable string literals (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) is (again) subject to *string interpolation*, this time based on *PowerShell*'s syntax rules; therefore, a value passed from `cmd.exe` could be subject to - possibly unwanted - interpretation, e.g. if you declare and use a variable such as `set VAR=$HOME` and even embedding *entire commands* is possible (e.g. `set VAR=$(1 + 2)`, which can be a *security risk*.
    - The techniques immediately below assume that the variable values themselves contain no `"` chars.; if they did, additional work would be needed, such as `` ""%VAR:"=`""%"" `` for `pwsh.exe`.
  - Avoid `\"%VAR%\"` inside overall `"..."`, because it breaks with values that contain `cmd.exe` metacharacters, such as in the case at hand; an example of a metacharacter that breaks the command even in *direct* invocation is `&`.
  - With **[`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)**, the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, use **`""`** as escaped `"` characters, which avoids the problem of `cmd.exe` seeing `%x%` as *unquoted*. That is,  using `""%VAR%""` inside overall `"..."` works robustly.
  - Unfortunately, with [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the legacy *Windows PowerShell* CLI, `""` does *not* work (robustly); the options are:

    - Use of **`\""`** (`\""%VAR%\""`) inside overall `"..."` quoting; however, while generally robust, it results in *whitespace normalization*, meaning that runs of *multiple* spaces are folded into a single one each.
    - This is rarely a problem in practice, but in cases where it is, you can use **`"^""`** (sic) in *direct* invocation; unfortunately, this doesn't work inside `for /f`, due to its buggy parsing, making a robust solution even more cumbersome: see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997805/45375).
- Using **`'...'` quoting**, i.e. a [verbatim, (single-quoted) PowerShell string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), is a better option:

  - Because `'` isn't a `cmd.exe` metacharacter (`cmd.exe` knows only `"..."` strings), it doesn't require escaping.
  - This can still break, however, namely if the variable value itself happens to contain `'` characters. It is possible but cumbersome to work around this, namely with `'%x:'=''%'`
  - Because PowerShell doesn't interpret the value of verbatim strings (except to handle escaped `'` chars.), the original variable value is used as-is.
- **Best option**: Using **`$env:VAR`** to get the value of `%VAR%`

  - `cmd.exe`'s variables - unlike PowerShell's - are invariably also *environment* variables, which any child process *inherits*. Therefore, the PowerShell command to execute can access the value of such variables using its `$env:` syntax (see [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables).
  - Doing so avoids the potentially problematic up-front string interpolation performed by `cmd.exe` (where, say, `%VAR%` on the PowerShell command line gets replaced with the value of that variable, as-is) and requires no quoting on the PowerShell side.
  - As with the `'...'` technique, the *verbatim* value of the variable is seen.
  - As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out, an **additional advantage is *security***:

    - By avoiding `cmd.exe`'s up-front string interpolation, any attempts at *code injection* are thwarted (the latter is primarily a risk with embedded `"..."` quoting, but can also affect embedded `'...'` quoting, if doubling `'` chars. embedded in the variable value is neglected).

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, in the modern, cross-platform edition of PowerShell, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), error messages are now (mostly) *single-line* by default.</sup>

Comment: In some ways, passing user data into a script as environment variables instead of embedding it in a string of dynamic Powershell code in the ```-Command``` argument is slightly more secure anyway, as it removes the opportunity for the user to craft data that performs code injection - e.g. ```set x=AAA\”);Format-Volume -DriveLetter C``` or similar. I’ve done it this way previously in a few sensitive Ansible / GitHub actions scenarios for that reason…