# How to replace text with different text, a newline and a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables, replace, newline

I am trying to find a specific word `(find)` and replace it with itself but add a newline and some other text via a variable after it like:

```
find
new text
```

My code looks like this:

```
powershell -command "$file=(gc file.txt);$var=(gc value.txt);$null=new-item -force $file -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $file) -replace ('find',$var) | out-string)"
```

How do I add the word `find` and a newline to the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell code:

```bash
-replace 'find', "`$0`n$var"
```

- `$0` in the substitution operand of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator refers to what the regex specified as the first operand matched.
- Note: `$0` is equivalent to `$&`, and even though the latter is more frequently used, the use of `$0` is deliberate - see below.
- Due to use of an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), the `$` of the `$0` placeholder must be escaped as `` `$ `` in order to be passed through to the .NET regex engine (which is the one processing such placeholders.
- `` "`n" `` is an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) that expands to a LF-only newline; use `` "`r`n" `` for a Windows-format CRLF newline, or `$([Environment]::NewLine)` for the platform-native newline format.
- `$var` embeds the (stringified) value of this variable in the resulting string

  - Note: `(gc value.txt)` (`Get-Content value.txt`) potentially returns *multiple* strings, namely one for each line, which are collected in an *array*. Stringifying such an array inside `"..."` turns it into a *single-line* representation, with the elements separated with *spaces*. Use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) `-Raw` to read a multi-line file as a whole (though you may then want to trim a *trailing* newline).

---

In the context of your PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call, from *outside* PowerShell:

Replace `-replace ('find',$var)` with:

```bash
-replace 'find', \"`$0`n$var\"
```

Note:

- `"` chars. must be `\`-escaped in order for PowerShell's command-line processing to preserve them as part of the code to subsequently execute.
- The above would *not* work if `$&` were used in lieu of `$0` when calling *from `cmd.exe` / a batch file*, because the `&` character would run afoul of `cmd.exe`'s parsing.

  - There are workarounds for cases where use of `&` (or other `cmd.exe` metacharacters, such as `^` and `|`) inside an embedded double-quoted string is a must - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth explanation! It works perfect!