# ipconfig shortened timeout by powershell

Tags: powershell, start-process

Windows shell command `ipconfig /renew "Ethernet 3"` have default timeout (in case there is no DHCP response) 120 secs. Want to short this timeout to 15 secs by powershell, but it complain `Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.`

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process 'ipconfig.exe' -ArgumentList '/renew', '"Ethernet 3"' -NoNewWindow -PassThru | % { if(-not $_.WaitForExit(15000)) { $_.Kill() } }"
```

Its just a slightly modified command utilizing ping.exe which work fine for me:

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process 'ping.exe' -ArgumentList '127.0.0.1', '-t' -NoNewWindow -PassThru | %% { if(-not $_.WaitForExit(15000)) { $_.Kill() } }"
```

seems that arguments are not passed correctly, what is a correct form of arguments scripting?

Comment: Or you can use start-job or start-threadjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You must *escape* `"` characters that you want [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, to see as part of the code to execute via the (positionally implied) `-Command` (`-c`) parameter.

  - Use `\"`<sup>[1]</sup>
- Additionally, when running your command *from a batch file*, you must escape `%` as `%%`, to prevent *`cmd.exe`* from interpreting it up front.

  - You can avoid this problem by using either the full name of the cmdlet that the `%` *alias* refers to, `ForEach-Object` or its other, word-based alias, `foreach`

Therefore (using *positional* parameter binding with `Start-Process` and a *single* `-ArgumentList` argument, optional quoting omitted):

```bash
powershell.exe "Start-Process ipconfig.exe '/renew \"Ethernet 3\"' -NoNewWindow -PassThru | foreach { if (-not $_.WaitForExit(15000)) { $_.Kill() } }"
```

---

<sup>[1] `\"` always works *for PowerShell*, but can situationally run afoul of *`cmd.exe`*'s up-front parsing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details and workarounds.</sup>