# Why does PowerShell split my command-line argument -a:b to become -a: b? How do I prevent it?

Tags: powershell

Running

```
powershell "& { $args }" "-a:b"
```

produces

```
-a:
b
```

How do I prevent this? It's super frustrating as I need to forward arguments as-is to other commands...

Comment: from where are you calling powershell? `powershell "& { $args } '-a:b'"` might solve your issue

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: That's annoying, I can't tell another app to use my script differently than every other script in the world. I'm trying to make a script `foo.ps1` containing `echo $args`. I need that to receive `-a:b` as-is when another app runs it. How do I do that? Every other interpreter in the world can do this...

Comment: issue is that for the parser `-a` is a parameter and `b` is the argument.

Comment: @user541686 "when another app runs it" doesn't tell us much about _how_ it will be invoked. `subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', '-Command', '&{echo $args}', '"-a:b"'], shell=True)` in python on Windows works for me (assuming you want the process to print the literal string `-a:b` to standard output).

Comment: Can you make use of the [ Stop-Parsisng](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.4#stop-parsing-token---) token? This works for me from the `Run` dialog:  `powershell -noexit -command & { $args }  --% -a:b`. It returns the operator itself, --%` as $Args[0], and `-a:b` as $Args[1]...

Comment: @KeithMiller: Hmm, not sure, maybe? I have to think about it. Definitely post it as an answer in any case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At the heart of your problem is a ***long-standing parameter-parsing/passing bug*: [GitHub issue #6292](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6292)**, first reported in 2018(!), still present as of PowerShell 7.4.1.

  - In short: something like `-a:b` - which *looks like* a named PowerShell argument targeting parameter `-a` with value `b`, but *isn't* in this case and shouldn't be treated as such - is unexpectedly broken into *two* (positional) arguments at the first `:`, i.e. into verbatim `-a:` and `b`
- Santiago and Mathias, in comments on the question, hint at what is - unfortunately - **the *only* viable workaround available at this time**:

  - Use the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter of the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell (where `-Command` is *implied*), [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+ (where `-File` (`-f`) is implied)) ...
  - ... *and* enclose `-a:b` in quotes (`'-a:b'` or `"-a:b"`, but note that on the command line the latter needs *escaping*, as `\"a:\b\"`) or - more simply - escape the initial `-` with `` ` `` (`` `-a:b ``), which forces `-a:b` to be passed *verbatim* as a single, *positional* argument.
  - E.g., from `cmd.exe` or from any *shell-free* context on Windows, all of the following work:

    ```bash
    powershell -Command "& { $args }" `-a:b
    powershell -Command "& { $args }" '-a:b'
    powershell -Command "& { $args }" \"-a:b\"
    ```

    - Note that since all all arguments following `-Command` are stitched back together with spaces during command-line parsing, after having removed syntactic (unescaped) `"` chars., you could use `"..."` enclosure around *all* arguments, which protects the arguments from accidental up-front interpretation by `cmd.exe` (not an issue in shell-free calls):<sup>[1]</sup>

      ```bash
      powershell -Command "& { $args } `-a:b"
      powershell -Command "& { $args } '-a:b'"
      powershell -Command "& { $args } \"-a:b\""
      ```
- Note that, due to the bug, **using the following is *not* an option at this time**, because doing so would require fixing the bug first:

  - The  `-File` CLI parameter (the default with `pwsh`), which is meant to use the arguments following the script path *verbatim*.
  - The `-CommandWithArgs` CLI parameter - still only an [experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) named [`PSCommandWithArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.4#pscommandwithargs) as of v7.4.x - which, similarly, is meant to pass arguments following the *first* one (assumed to be the script block to which all subsequent arguments are to be passed) verbatim.

    - That is, if the bug *didn't* exist, the following would work - note that `$args` is used in isolation, because the first argument is then *implicitly* treated like a function capable of receiving arguments:

      ```bash
       :: !! Does NOT work as of PowerShell 7.4.1
       pwsh -CommandWithArgs "$args" -a:b
      ```

---

<sup>[1] Embedding `\"...\"` arguments in an overall `"..."` command can still run afoul of `cmd.exe`'s parsing, however. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for workarounds.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is sad to hear. I hate Powershell... it's _so_ close to being awesome, but some critical stuff is just painful/impossible.

Comment: I empathize, @user541686: many small, but annoying bugs relating to parameter-passing, especially when calling external programs from inside PowerShell sessions, have been known for years but were never addressed. (That said, these bugs may not be small in terms of the _effort required to fix them_: My sense is that the underlying component, the parameter binder, is a complex beast, and that there's a fear of touching it lest something else break).

Comment: @mklement0 : Actually, the documentation for the stop parsing token mentions that it's passed along as an argument -- so it is working as expected.

Comment: @mklement0: The very lsdt output code block, right before**"See Also"** : `C:\Users\username|--%|$HOME`.

Comment: That code is a***quote*** from the documentation -- output from example. I appreciate your expounding and am grateful not looking to quarrel. I just scanned and saw it hadn't been mentioned. Wasn't trying to compare as an alternate answer -- just thought OP and others should be aware of its existence.

Comment: @mklement0: The [documentation that I linked to in my initial comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.4#stop-parsing-token---) is the source of the quoted code -- that's all.

Comment: @KeithMiller, un/fortunately, there's more to this story, and I will file a new issue. Again, I appreciate the discussion, and sorry for not realizing that you were talking about a different piece of the documentation than I was.

Comment: @KeithMiller, I've cleaned up most of my previous comments, and I've filed two new issues: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10889 to address the example that you quoted, and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10888 to address the - narrowly constrained - uses of `--%` with _PowerShell_ commands. Because of the latter, I've removed references to `--%` from my answer. In short: with PowerShell commands, use of `--%` only makes sense if you're _relaying arguments to native programs_, using _splatting_. Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: @mklement0: will take a look when I'm at a computer with a decent-sized monitor. I'm legally blind due to central vision loss -- require high zoom/magnification if I want to focus on content without the frustration of trying to make out the words!

Comment: Understood, @KeithMiller (I am sorry to hear that). To me, the conclusion is: `--%` only makes sense if you're, possibly indirectly, calling an _external program_. If you try to use it in PowerShell code, you'll see whatever (unparsed) arguments followed `--%` as a _single string_; with splatting of `@args` in a call to an external program, that is just a pass-through operation and works as intended, but if you wanted to process the arguments in PowerShell, you'd have to parse them yourself. In your Super User answer that happened not to be a problem, due to there being just _one_ argument.

Comment: True. And ive never used it before, so no expectations of its behavior. I saw it as a "one-liner here-string"...