How can I start a powershell script with parameters from a batch file
I would like to start a powershell script from a batch file and ensure the script closes before the batch file proceeds to the next step. I've been unable to figure out how to even launch the script with parameters.
The following command works when run in directly PowerShell:
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"C:\my file path\myscript.ps1`" -fruit banana -car toyota"

However I need to be able to run this from a batch file (CMD). The below does not work.
Seems to be an issue with quoting but unfortunately single quotes are ignored.
powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"C:\my file path\myscript.ps1`" -fruit banana -car toyota' -Wait"

Why doesn't this work and why don't single quotes work?

How to run a PowerShell script from a batch file

@Compo, karel, Gerhard, I don't think the cite duplicate, has the same question (it's about passing the ExecutionPolicy to the admin account), yet the aswers deal with the same problem as the question here. What have tried to do with my answer to this specific question, is to give two common directions that might result in a easier and cleaner solution. Anyways, I can't deny that there are indeed several duplicates out there (as covered in my answer).

The (quoting) invocation issue here, is actually a quite common and repeating type of question, see e.g.:

Escaping quotes in powershell.exe via command prompt
How do I escape "Quotes" in a powershell string?
Escape double quotes in powershell -Command

Meaning that I could just answer this specific command line that does work instead but I rather give you some general guidance:
In the invocation examples in this answer, I use the following C:\my file path\myscript.ps1:
Param($Fruit, $Car)
Write-Host 'Fruit:' $Fruit
Write-Host 'Car:' $Car
$Null = Read-Host 'Press <enter> to continue'

Keep it simple 
Often, in situations like this, there are more shells and processes embedded than necessarily. This makes the command expensive and increases the complexity of the command line. As in your example, there is no reason to use the Start-Process cmdlet to "ensure the script closes before the batch file proceeds to the next step". PowerShell's dot-sourcing feature allows you to invoke your script with an easier and less expensive command:
. 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit banana -car toyota

Dot-sourced commands also run synchronously. A difference with Start-Process
though, is that they run in the same scope of the caller (see: about scopes) but that shouldn't be issue when invoking a single script from a CLI (command line interface) as PowerShell.exe or CMD.exe.
This means if you want invoke your script from PowerShell.exe, you could do:
PowerShell -NoProfile -Command { . 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit banana -car toyota }

Note that the PowerShell.exe command given from the PowerShell host gives you an extra possibility to enclose a script, which is using curly brackets ({ ... }) rather than embedding your command (that already migth contain quotes) in a new string. In other words, within the ScriptBlock (enclosed by the curly brackets) the standard quoting rules apply.
Besides, if you want invoke your script from PowerShell.exe command-line interface, you might also directly invoke your script using the -File parameter:
PowerShell -NoProfile -File 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit banana -car toyota

The double-quote monster 
I probably took already away all the fun with the last command line that should also work from the CMD command line if you replace the single quotes with double quotes:
PowerShell -NoProfile -File "C:\my file path\myscript.ps1" -fruit banana -car toyota

But let's assume that you would like to use a cmdlet as Start-Process with a parameter that needs to be quoted as in your example: -File "C:\my file path\myscript.ps1". As apposed to PowerShell, the CMD command line only understands double quotes for argument enclosure, and...
Here comes the crux: PowerShell.exe eats double quotes!
The double quotes are used to enclose arguments but they are basically gone ones the argument is determined (btw. it doesn't understand curly brackets when the PowerShell.exe command is given from the CMD command line).
To prove this (using the CMD command line):
PowerShell -Command ". 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit ba"na"na -car to"yo"ta"
Fruit: banana
Car: toyota


Note
When you invoke the same command from the (Windows) PowerShell CLI it is somewhat smarter how it handles quotes, but the difference makes it sometimes even more confusing.

So, the easiest way to get around this, is simply avoid any embedded double quotes and use single quotes ('...') or even no quotes where possible for the PowerShell arguments which is less of an issue if you simplified the invocation:
PowerShell -Command ". 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit 'ba na na' -car toyota"
Fruit: ba na na
Car: toyota


Note 1
A PowerShell command given from the CMD command line still requires to enclose the outer CMD argument with double quotes if it contains any spaces.


Note2
In argument mode, PowerShell doesn't require any quoting (as in -fruit banana) unless the argument contains special characters (including spaces).

And in case you really are in need to pass double quotes, you are required to escape them to: \"", e.g.:
PowerShell -Command ". 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit '\""Banana\""' -Car '\""Toyota\""'
Fruit: "Banana"
Car: "Toyota"

For details on this, I recommend you to read the helpful answer from mklement0 about the tricky double quote exceptions and how to robustly escape them when calling (PowerShell) from cmd.exe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/1701026

Thanks for the detailed answer but there are still some problems. Please note for this example command:
PowerShell -NoProfile -File 'C:\my file path\myscript.ps1' -fruit banana -car toyota
This (and seemingly anything with single quotes) does not work from CMD. It seems to ignore the single quotes and gives the below error:
Processing -File ''C:\my' failed: The given path's format is not supported. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter.

Thanks. Ended up using backslashes instead of backtick.
powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"C:\my file path\myscript.ps1\" -fruit banana -car toyota' -Wait"
Unfortunately I wasn't able to get your suggestion to work using dot sourcing.

@Shupershuff: PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\my file path\myscript.ps1" -fruit banana -car toyota (as also shown in the answer) is simpler and more efficient (avoids creating two powershell.exe instances).
