# problem with powershell and cmd with pipes

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have this command that works ok on powershell

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content "tex1.txt") (Get-Content "tex2.txt") | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | select inputobject |  ft -hidetableheaders
```

I'm trying to running in cmd by doing this:

```
powershell -Command " & {Compare-Object (Get-Content "tex1.txt") (Get-Content "tex2.txt") | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | select inputobject |  ft -hidetableheaders}"
```

but it says something like: the name, the directory or the volume syntax is incorrect (is in spanish so i dont know the exact translation)

I think the problem is the pipes, since running everything before the pipe: `Compare-Object (Get-Content "tex1.txt") (Get-Content "tex2.txt")` works

PD: I also tried to write `^` before the pipes but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: No, it's not the pipes. To CMD this command looks like the following elements: `" & {Compare-Object (Get-Content "`, `tex1.txt`, `") (Get-Content "`, `tex2.txt`, `") | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "`, `<=`, `"} | select inputobject | ft -hidetableheaders}"`. For "<=", CMD ignores the "=" as a whitespace character, so it's handled as `<` standard input redirection. For this it tries to open "} | select inputobject | ft -hidetableheaders}" for reading, which fails with `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` because "|" is a reserved character in the file system (e.g. NTFS or FAT).

Comment: Inside the command, try replacing QUOTE characters with APOSTROPHE characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**

When calling the PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for the cross-platform *PowerShell [Core] 6+* edition):

- Using embedded `"` in an overall `"..."` string comes with escaping challenges.
- If feasible for a given command, formulating it *without* embedded `"` is the easiest solution:

```
powershell -Command "Compare-Object (Get-Content tex1.txt) (Get-Content tex2.txt) | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | select inputobject |  ft -hidetableheaders"
```

Read on, if you do need to use embedded `"`.

---

[eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) points out that your problem is your *lack of escaping of embedded `"` chars.* inside the overall `"..."` string, which causes `cmd.exe` to see *multiple* strings, including parts it considers *unquoted*, which causes problems with special characters such as `|` and `<` - they never reach *PowerShell*.

*Nesting* double-quote strings from `cmd.exe` is tricky business:

- To make `cmd.exe` happy, you need to *double* the embedded `"` chars. (`""`)
- Separately, to make `powershell.exe` happy, you need to `\`-escape `"` chars.

  - Note: PowerShell [Core] 6+, the cross-platform edition, on Windows now also accepts `""` by itself, which is the most robust choice.

Generally, dealing with quoting and escaping arguments when calling from `cmd.exe` is a frustrating experience with no universal solutions, unlike in the Unix world. Sadly, *PowerShell* has its own challenges, even in the Unix world.<sup>[1]</sup>

In short: **Escape embedded `"` chars. when calling the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, `powershell.exe`, from `cmd.exe`** as follows (for the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, **`pwsh.exe`**, **`""`** is the robust choice):

- **Use `"^""`** (sic) when using `powershell.exe -Command`, which works robustly.

  - **Caveat**: `"^""` **does *not* work for calling *other* programs**.
  - This **saves you from additional escaping**, as would be necessary if you used `\"`
  - **Example**: `powershell -command " Write-Output "^""a  &  b"^"" "` yields `a  &  b`, as expected, and the `&` didn't need escaping.
- **If you use the simpler - and customary - `\"`**, **you *may* need to perform additional escaping**: Specifically, you **must *individually `^`-escape* the following `cmd.exe` metacharacters with `^` inside `\"...\"` runs: `& | < > ^`**<sup>Thanks, [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings).</sup>

  - **Example**: `powershell -command " Write-Output \"a  ^&  b\" "` yields `a  &  b`; that is, the `&` needed escaping with `^`.
- Additionally, to treat `%` (and, with `enabledelayedexpansion` , `!`) *verbatim*, the escaping syntax unfortunately depends on whether you're calling from the *command line* or a *batch file*: use `%^USERNAME%` (`!^USERNAME`) from the former, and `%%USERNAME%%` (`^!USERNAME^!` / `^^!USERNAME^^!` inside `\"...\"` runs) from the latter - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375) for the gory details.

It is unfortunate that `cmd.exe` makes use of `\"` treacherous, given that it is supported by virtually all programs (except batch files), and if it weren't for these extra escaping requirements, command lines that use it have the potential to work across different platforms and shells - with the notable exception of calling *from PowerShell*, where, sadly, an additional layer of escaping is needed and `"` inside `"..."` must be escaped as `` \`" `` (sic); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

See the bottom section for ways to ease the escaping pain by avoiding use of nested `"`.

---

**Other programs, including PowerShell *Core*:**

- **Use *just* `""`** for **programs compiled with *Microsoft* compilers and, on Windows, also *Python* and *Node.js* as well as PowerShell *Core* (`pwsh.exe`)**.
  Regrettably, this robust option does *not* work with `powershell.exe`, i.e. *Windows PowerShell*.
- **Use `\"`** for **programs with Unix heritage, such as Perl and Ruby** - which comes with the escaping headaches discussed above.

---

#### Avoiding embedded `"`:

**When you call PowerShell's CLI, you can often get away *without* needing to embed *double* quotes**:

- There may be arguments in your string that don't require quoting at all, such as `text1.txt` and `text2.txt`
- You can alternatively use *single*-quoting (`'...'`) inside the overall command string, which require no escaping; note that such strings, from PowerShell's perspective, are string *literals*.

To put it all together:

```
powershell -Command "Compare-Object (Get-Content tex1.txt) (Get-Content tex2.txt) | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | select inputobject |  ft -hidetableheaders"
```

<sup>Note that I've also removed the `& { ... }` around your command, as it isn't necessary.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) puts it as follows: "This is the inescapable frustration of the Windows command line. Every program parses its own command line, using whatever rules it wants. So the syntax of a command line has to work with not only the shell (CMD) but also all programs invoked in the pipeline. In the Unix world the shell parses the command line into `argv` arrays, so typically you only have to get the syntax right to make the shell happy."

The problems with PowerShell Core, even on Unix, stem from how it re-quotes arguments behind the scenes before passing them on - see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361).</sup>