# Running PowerShell command from CMD gives positional parameter error

Tags: powershell, cmd, escaping, quoting

I have this PowerShell command:

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'ost'" |
    Select-Object 'Name' |
    Out-File C:\temp\ost.txt -Append
```

But I need to run it form a command prompt. I'm running it like this:

```batch
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'ost'" | Select-Object 'Name' | Out-File C:\temp\ost.txt -Append"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Get-WmiObject : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Query Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'os ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

How do I run this correctly?

Comment: Use single-quotes for the `-Query` parameter and escape your double-quotes with `^`.

Comment: Escape the nested double quotes with backslashes: `"Get-WmiObject -Query \"Select * from ...\" | ..."`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Why ``\``? I thought the `cmd` escape was `^`

Comment: Don't ask me why. All I can tell you is that `^` is the escape character in CMD *most* of the time. ;)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: It is _PowerShell_ that requires `\ `-escaping of `"` chars. _when processing CLI arguments_. `cmd.exe` ignores the `\ ` itself, though its treating the following `"` as a syntax element then brings its own challenges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *escape* the *nested* `"` chars. in your command, which is most robustly done as `\""` (sic):

```
PowerShell.exe -c  "Get-WmiObject -Query \""Select * ... 'ost'\"" | Select ..."
```

**Caveat**: Use of `\""` works well and robustly with `powershell.exe`, (and `pwsh` for PowerShell *Core*) but not with *other* programs, such as `python`, `ruby`, `perl` or `node`.

See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528089/45375) for a detailed explanation, including how to escape for other programs.