# Why the Powershell command replace not working for me

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace a string in a file like this:

```
c:\>powershell -Command (gc D:\xxxxxxx\index.html) ^   
 -replace '^<script src="js/locale/languageholder.js"^>^</script^>', '' ^
| Out-File -encoding ASCII "D:\yyyyyyyyy\index.html"
```

the string I want to remove is:

```
<script src="js/locale/languageholder.js"></script>
```

no errors, but it is just not replaced. I assume there must be some charactors to be escaped, but couldn't figure it out.

In the code ^ is used to escape <, otherwise it will show this error:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

Getting the same error using \ to escape

Comment: `-replace` is a regex operator and `^` is a regex metacharacter describing the starting position of a string.  Since no string starts in multiple places, it doesn't work. If you're expecting to find a literal caret `^` you need to escape it with a backslash, eg. `\^<script src=...`

Comment: without ^ there will be error on <, ^ is used to escape. Tried with your suggestion ,doesn't work either, but thanks a lot.

Comment: `^` is not an escape sequence in neither regex nor PowerShell. Are you running this from a batch script? Or interactively from `cmd.exe`?

Comment: I run this from a batch file, also directly from cmd.exe, same result

Comment: Please update the question with this detail (it's quite important, "< was unexpected at this time." is from `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell)

Comment: Sorry, @MathiasR.Jessen I have a complex batch file, that is just part of the script, I should have made it with more detail. The question is updated with your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to `\`-escape all `"` characters that you want to *pass through* to the PowerShell command** that is ultimately executed, after the PowerShell CLI has stripped *unescaped* `"` characters, if any, during *command-line parsing*:

```
powershell -Command (gc D:\xxxxxxx\index.html) ^   
 -replace '^<script src=\"js/locale/languageholder.js\"^>^</script^>', '' ^
  | Out-File -encoding ASCII \"D:\yyyyyyyyy\index.html\"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528089/45375) for more information.

Comment: correct, escaping " is the tricky part. I tried, it works. Thank you mklement0!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Gisway.; my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have an external powershell file:

replace.ps1:

```
(gc index.html) -replace '<script src="js/locale/languageholder.js"></script>' |
  set-content index2.html
```

Then run:

```
powershell -file replace.ps1
```