# Passing Powershell from Cmd with variable evaluation

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to use the following command

```
powershell -command "get-content %CONFIG_FILE% | %{$_ -replace \"APP_PATH=.+\",\"APP_PATH=%APP_DIR%\"}"
```

but with the evaluation of the %CONFIG_FILE% and the %APP_DIR% which are defined in the batch script using

```
set CONFIG_FILE=C:\B0_GW.cfg 
set APP_DIR=C:\dbg\kernel
```

when i do so, i currently get the following issue:

> The string is missing the terminator: ".
>
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

any ideas?

Comment: I guess you need to escape the `%`-symbol in `%{$_` by doubling it: `%%{$_`...

Comment: In the Batch file, below the two `set` commands, put: `powershell get-content %CONFIG_FILE% ^| %%{$_ -replace \"APP_PATH=.+\",\"APP_PATH=%APP_DIR%\"}` or just `powershell get-content %CONFIG_FILE% ^| %%{$_ -replace "APP_PATH=.+","APP_PATH=%APP_DIR%"}`

Comment: @Aacini: It's better to keep the enclosing `"..."` around the PowerShell code, because without them an `%APP_PATH%` value with two or more adjacent embedded spaces (however rare that may be) will break the command.
Your 2nd suggestion always breaks, because PowerShell strips unescaped `"` during CLI parsing _before_ interpreting the code.

Answer (score 2):

[aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

**From within a *batch file*<sup>[1]</sup>, you must *escape* `%` characters that you want to *pass through* to the target application *as `%%`*.**

Otherwise, `cmd` interprets `%` as the start or end of an *environment-variable reference* (which in part happens *by design* in your command; e.g., `%CONFIG_FILE%`).

(You've already correctly escaped *embedded `"` chars.* in your command as `\"` for PowerShell).

Specifically, the `%` in the `%{...}` part of your command needs escaping (`%` is  PowerShell's built-in alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet):

```
powershell -command "get-content %CONFIG_FILE% | %% {$_ -replace \"APP_PATH=.+\",\"APP_PATH=%APP_DIR%\"}"
```

Alternatively, simply use the cmdlet's actual name, `ForEach-Object`, which obviates the need for escaping:

```
powershell -command "get-content %CONFIG_FILE% | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace \"APP_PATH=.+\",\"APP_PATH=%APP_DIR%\"}"
```

---

<sup>[1] Sadly, the behavior at `cmd.exe`'s *command prompt* (in an interactive session) differs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375).</sup>