# System.getenv with special characters like '%' in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables, special-characters, getenv

My JAR runs in a DOS shell like this

```
set MY_VAR=MY_VALUE
my_jar.jar MyClass
```

and in MyClass I code

```java
String myValue = System.getenv("MY_VAR");
System.out.println("myValue = " + myValue);
```

This works fine.

But now I must change in my DOS shell the value of MY_VAR from MY_VALUE to MY%VALUE.

```
set MY_VAR=MY%VALUE
my_jar.jar MyClass
```

I can't use this value because the '%' character has disappeared.
I dump also myValue in my code to stdout:

```
myValue = MYVALUE
```

What is the cause for the disappearance of the '%' character and how can I set a value with '%' characters in the shell and use it in the Java code?

Comment: This is not java related but more a problem with windows batch files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907057/ignore-percent-sign-in-batch-file for a hint on how to solve.

Comment: Try `set MY_VAR=MY%%VALUE` in your batch file.

Comment: @saka1029 Thank you. This was the solution.