# Batch file uploading entire folder to FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am trying to upload entire a folder to ftp but it just uploads one file, what could be the problem?

Open *Run* window → `cmd` → `ftp -s:C:\ftpfile.bat`

This is my batch code code:

```
open FTP address
USERNAME
PASSWORD
bin
mput C:\user\*
bye
```

Thanks from now.

Comment: check this post --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601161/copying-all-contents-of-folder-to-another-folder-using-batch-file

Comment: Thanks Pradeep but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [`prompt`](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#prompt) before `mput` in order to deactivate interactive mode?

```
open FTP address
USERNAME
PASSWORD
prompt
bin
mput C:\user\*
bye
```