# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect issue

Tags: syntax, directory

I'm trying to execute a basic query from command prompt below and always got the response as " The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 0 file copied.

```
copy /y “C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\Source_File\*.*” “C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\TAN\”
```

Comment: Are you using different quotation characters ? They look different " “

Comment: @Peter: I changed them to be the same now and the issue is still remained.

Comment: Put the error in the question as well please

Answer (score 0):

Use XCOPY instead. See this question [copying all contents of folder to another folder using batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601161/copying-all-contents-of-folder-to-another-folder-using-batch-file)

```
xcopy /s /y "C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\Source_File" "C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\TAN"
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it as you said and the code went through.

Comment: I have a full code to copy files in listed txt file to another folder as below. However, I got an error came back as "%%I was unexpected at this time." and " File not found - %%I*"
  for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\Filelist1.txt) do (
     xcopy /s /y “C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\Souce_File\%%i*” “C:\Users\tdnguyen\Desktop\TAN\”
    )

Comment: Maybe you can put that in another question. Asking questions in the comments sections defeats the purpose of StackOverflow