# Batch Argument with quotes and spaces

Tags: batch-file, escaping

The batch file `args.bat` is for testing purposes:

```
@echo off
echo Arguments 1 to 4:
echo.%~1
echo.%~2
echo.%~3
echo.%~4
```

The batch file is using `~` to remove the leading and trailing quotation mark, and it should display the following values to the user:

```
Argument 1
This is "Argument 2".
```

For argument 1, it's easy:

```
args.bat "Argument 1"
```

However, for argument 2, things are not working well, no matter what escape sequence I try (I found several here on Stack Overflow):

```
// Didn't expect this to work, but for completeness
>args.bat "Argument 1" "This is "Argument 2"."
Arguments 1 to 4:
Argument 1
This is "Argument
2"."
```

Escaping with double quotes somehow passes the double quotes on:

```
>args.bat "Argument 1" "This is ""Argument 2""."
Arguments 1 to 4:
Argument 1
This is ""Argument 2"".
```

Escaping with circumflex:

```
>args.bat "Argument 1" "This is ^"Argument 2^"."
Arguments 1 to 4:
Argument 1
This is "Argument
2"."
```

Escape with backslash:

```
>args.bat "Argument 1" "This is \"Argument 2\"."
Arguments 1 to 4:
Argument 1
This is \"Argument
2\"."
```

Be sure I tried a whole bunch of other stuff (ultimately thinking of brute-forcing a solution, but asking the question first), each resulting in funny output but never what I want:

```
>args.bat "Argument 1" ^"This is ^^"Argument^" 2^^"."
Arguments 1 to 4:
Argument 1
This is "Argument" 2".
```

Is it possible to pass a parameter to my batch file like I want without changing the batch file? If not, is there a way of running `cmd` in a special mode so that it treats the parameters like I want?

I have seen solutions doing a search and replace of double quotes, but I really want the batch file unchanged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script)

Comment: @BenjyKessler: I read the answers there and in my question you'll find I tried both, the double quote and circumflex escape characters. None of them work.

Answer (score 7):

You can't bring such an argument into `%1` (or any other `%<n>`).

But with a little trick it's possible.

args.bat arg1 "This is !q!Argument 2!q!"

And args.bat looks like

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "q=""
echo * = %*
echo 1 = %~1
echo 2 = %~2
```

Or also this is possible

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "arg1=%~1"
set "arg2=%~2"
echo * = %*
echo 1 = %arg1:""="%
echo 2 = %arg2:""="%
```

Then you can call it with `args.bat "This is ""Argument 1"""`

When you don't want to work with this technic you could also decide to parse the arguments by yourself.
Then you need to take all argumtents from `%*` and go through each character.

**Edit**
If you can't modify the scripts at all, then you could use the first solution one modification.

At the command prompt.

```
C:\SomeDir> cmd /V:ON 
C:\SomeDir> set "q=""
C:\SomeDir> args.bat argument1 "This is ^!q^!Argument 2^!q^!"
```

Or as one-liner

```
cmd /v:on /c set ^^^"q=^^^"^^^" ^& test "This is ^!q^!Argument 2^!q^!"
```

Using this enables the enabled delayed mode before entering the batch file, this can have some other **undesired side effects** in the called batch file if it doesn't handle this case properly.

Comment: But can it be done without editing the script at all? That's how I'm reading the question. I imagine this is for work and there's a script deployment system in place that requires all changes to be reviewed and tested thoroughly, which can cause delays days or weeks long.

Comment: You are right, I added a solution which doesn't require script modifications