# How to pass a argument including double quotes in plink ( Windows )

Tags: plink

Handling double quotes in Plink (Windows) is very hard.
I need to send a argument including a double quote on both side but even though I tried lots of \", "\", "\"", I got several errors as following.

```
plink.exe  -ssh -l testacct -pw  kajskldf 10.31.137.199 " myexe where "id > 6000" "

The system cannot find the path specified.
or
Argument for 'where' option must be bounded by ""
```

Can you let me know how I can pass this kind of argument to a linux server?

## UPDATE

This syntax works.

```
plink.exe  -ssh -l testacct -pw  kajskldf 10.31.137.199 " myexe where \\\""id \> 6000\\\"" "
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script)

Comment: I.e. this should work: `plink.exe ... 10.31.137.199 "myexe where ""id > 6000"""`

Comment: It works now with the syntax put in Question. Thank you!