# Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have integrated Elasticsearch (Version 5.5) into Gitlab and try to use it. This is the command I send from an external windows client:

```
curl -XGET gitlab.server:9200/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"query": {"simple_query_string" : {"fields" : ["content"], "query" : "foo bar -baz"}}}'
```

but it doesn't work. On the client I get these errors:

> {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: text
>   curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
>   curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
>   curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
>   curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
>   curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: query
>   curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
>   curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 13

On the server in /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log I can see no log messages.

However, running the same exact command as above from the linux server gives me a response without errors:

```
{
  "name" : "name",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "uuid",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.0",
    "build_hash" : "260387d",
    "build_date" : "2017-06-30T23:16:05.735Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I tried adding `http.content_type.required: true` to the elasticsearch.yml, but the problem was the same. So, what am I doing wrong here? Why do I get a "Content-Type header not supported" from the Windows client? How can I solve this?

After changing the ' to " like this:

```
curl -XGET gitlab.server:9200/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"query": {"simple_query_string" : {"fields" : ["content"], "query" : "foo bar -baz"}}}"
```

I recieve this response:

```
{
  "name" : "name",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "uuid",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.0",
    "build_hash" : "260387d",
    "build_date" : "2017-06-30T23:16:05.735Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bar
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with quotes on windows. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834238/curl-post-command-line-on-windows-restful-service and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680899/curl-issues-with-api-call-could-not-resolve-host

Comment: @bless: See my edit. It looks better (as in, I actually recieve a response) but there still seems to be something wrong with the command.

Comment: Can you update the question with the command you ran after changing the ' to "?

Comment: @bless: I did as you asked.

Comment: Think you might have to escape the quotes `-d "{\"query\": {\"simple_query_string\" : {\"fields\" : [\"content\"], \"query\" : \"foo bar -baz\"}}}"`

Comment: @bless: Okay, I will try that on monday. Cheers!

Comment: @bless: I now tried it with escaped quotation marks and got a response without any error messages. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Posted as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: In my case it worked just by providing the option `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` which I was missing. Thanks for making the question :)

Comment: @FedeGarcia Cheers. Judging from all the upvotes this question received, we are not alone with problems like this. ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

After changing the enclosing quotes from `'` to `"`, escape the quotation marks `"` used inside the parameters as below:

```
curl -XGET gitlab.server:9200/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"query\": {\"simple_query_string\" : {\"fields\" : [\"content\"], \"query\" : \"foo bar -baz\"}}}"
```

An [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087438/1421222) is to put the json into a file, and use the `@` prefix for the parameters.

**json.txt**

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : { 
      "fields" : ["content"], 
      "query" : "foo bar -baz"
    }
  }
}
```

and run curl as below:

```
curl -XGET gitlab.server:9200/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @json.txt
```