# elasticsearch index creation problems for Linkedin WhereHows installation

Tags: elasticsearch

Going through the installation steps for installing Linkedin's `WhereHows` tool (https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/blob/master/wherehows-docs/getting-started.md#elasticsearch-setup), having problems setting up `elasticsearch` indexes.

Following the elasticsearch installation instructions (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/running-elasticsearch.html) for tar file, everything seems to be set up fine:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
{
  "name" : "TjtCCG8",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "LFsoqrBMSRCn80eHVWxYvw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.4",
    "build_hash" : "ccec39f",
    "build_date" : "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But then running the command

```
curl -XPUT '$YOUR_INDEX_URL:9200/wherehows' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "dataset": {},
    "comment": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "dataset"
      }
    },
    "field": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "dataset"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

we see the error

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

** Note: I have seen this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289099/8236733, but escaping the quotations in various ways did not appear to fix things:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/wherehows' -d '
{
  \"mappings\": {
    \"dataset\": {},
    \"comment\": {
      \"_parent\": {
        \"type\": \"dataset\"
      }
    },
    \"field\": {
      \"_parent\": {
        \"type\": \"dataset\"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/wherehows -d "
{
  \"mappings\": {
    \"dataset\": {},
    \"comment\": {
      \"_parent\": {
        \"type\": \"dataset\"
      }
    },
    \"field\": {
      \"_parent\": {
        \"type\": \"dataset\"
      }
    }
  }
}
"
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

Adding a content header for json, I see the error

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/wherehows' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "
{
  \"mappings\": {
    \"dataset\": {},
    \"comment\": {
      \"_parent\": {
        \"type\": \"dataset\"
      }
    },
    \"field\": {
      \"_parent\": {
        \"type\": \"dataset\"
      }
    }
  }
}
"
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [wherehows] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [field, comment, dataset]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [wherehows] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [field, comment, dataset]"},"status":400}
```

(Should note here that is says "rejecting mapping update", but really the index has not even actually been yet). Getting similar error when using a json file to hold the mapping.

Does anyone know what could be happening here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by installing a 5.6.9 version of elasticsearch (https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-5-6-9). Then running something like

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/wherehows \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d @wherehows-es-indexes.setup.json
```

(where I keep the json mapping in the wherehows-es-indexes.setup.json file simply for convenience).

Apparantly elasticsearch versions > 5.x do not support multiple type mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html#removal-of-types) (which the Linkedin WhereHows installation instructions apparently need).

Also relevant: https://www.elastic.co/support/eol

(I wonder if the WhereHows developers are doing anything about this)