# Triple quotes required on command line in QB64

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

Have a program which parses the command line in QB64. The COMMAND$ function
returns the command line. I need to parse a long filename which might contain
a space by parsing it from within quotes to differ from a filename with no
space. For example, "long filename.ext"

The problem is that, when the command line has no quotes, the command$ returns
the filename, when in quotes, the same, for example "filename", and ""filename"" both return filename. However, """filename""" returns the
filename with quotes... Is there another way to send a quote to command$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QB64 provides the `COMMAND$` and `_COMMANDCOUNT` functions—mostly analogous to `argv` and `argc` in C++. `COMMAND$` without arguments will return a single string containing all command line args, but QB64 also allows `COMMAND$(i)` to retrieve the argument at index `i` as a string. Example from the [`_COMMANDCOUNT` entry](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/COMMANDCOUNT) on the QB64 Wiki:

```
limit = _COMMANDCOUNT
FOR i = 1 TO limit
    PRINT COMMAND$(i)
NEXT
```

You'd use them to deal with the command-line arguments in QB64. If you want to pass command-line args that include quotes to a program, you'd likely need to escape the quotes you want kept using a backslash.

Unfortunately, the backslash escape isn't foolproof and can lead to trouble in `cmd.exe` specifically, mainly because backslashes are used in file paths. Combine this with spaces in a file path, and you have a nightmarish command interpreter. From [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/539810), you double the quotes inside a quoted string to pass a proper quote to a program:

```
> program.exe hello world
hello
world

> program.exe hello"" world
hello (+ empty quoted string)
world

> program.exe "hello"" world
hello"
world

> program.exe "hello""" world
hello" world
```

In Wine's `cmd.exe`, the `""` escaped quote also closes the quoted string as shown above, so an immediately successive quote is needed to continue grouping the next spaced item with the current argument. I'm not sure about the Windows implementation since I'm not running a Windows machine, but it seems likely to me that the same behavior occurs.

In other words, you pass `"""filename"""` because:

```
"        Open quoted string
""       Escaped double quote, closes quoted string
filename Concatenated at the end of the first quoted string
"        Open quoted string, concatenated to filename
""       Escaped double quote, closes quoted string
```

**Edit**

You can use `^"` outside of a quoted string, but that has its own issues as `""^"` results in `"` for example, just like `"""`. Passing `""^"` to a batch file requires an extra escape as `""^^"`. Using `^` is therefore not recommended, especially when `""` and `"""` work just as well. See the answer I linked above for info on the `^` escape character.

You should also be careful with backslashes and quoted strings. Consider how you might pass the proper Windows representation of the Unix-like argument `'C:/Program Files/"file" name'` as a single argument to your program:

```
> program.exe "C:\Program Files\\""file\"" name"
C:\Program Files\"file" name
```

`cmd.exe` explanation:

```
"                   Open quoted string
C:\Program Files\\  Quoted string contents, including escaped \
""                  Escaped double quote, closes quoted string
file\               Unquoted string contents, including C escape char
""                  Open quoted string with escaped double quote
[ ]name             Quoted string contents
"                   Close quoted string
```

This results in a command-line of `"C:\Program Files\\"file\" name"` being passed to the program, which then results in a path of `C:\Program Files\"file" name`. Of course, such a path isn't possible in Windows (and maybe not at all on NTFS filesystems?), but it illustrates the point: you need to account for both `cmd.exe`'s quoting rules and the C runtime's quoting rules and backslash escapes.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was ^" to escape the quote, it is a backslash. Thanks for helping again Chrono.

Comment: In a batch file, `^"` can be used, but in an interactive session, you may want `""` (to start/end a quoted string with a quote char) or `"""` (to end a quoted string with a quote char and start a new quoted string). The answer I linked has a lot of details about various escape rules with respect to quotes. I also edited my answer to help clarify some things regarding backslash escapes and double quotes. You need to be careful when dealing with `cmd.exe`. If possible, use another command interpreter—Bash is ideal, whether it's WSL bash, git-bash, or even the bash versions in Cygwin or MSYS.