# Run schtasks.exe with PowerShell command from command prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to run the *schtasks.exe* as administrator using `PowerShell -Command` with `Start-Process` to create a task.
This is the code of my `.bat` file I've got so far.

```
 set mydir=%~dp0
 set mydir2=%mydir%prim.exe
 set mys='`"C:\workspace\prim.exe`"'
 Powershell -Command "&{Start-Process -FilePath schtasks -ArgumentList '/Create', '/SC ONLOGON', '/TN CoUpdater', '/IT', '/RL HIGHEST', '/TR', '\"%mydir2%\"' -verb RunAs}"
```

At first I set up my path to the program I want to run. The problem is that my path name contains some white spaces. After some research I was able to determine that the path is in the task scheduler but without quotes (argument after /TR ):

[image: Task scheduler 1]

The next thing I did was adding of quotes to a string and put it as the argument after /TR

```
set mys='`"C:\workspace\prim.exe`"'
```

which results in:
[image: Task scheduler 2]

But now I don't know how I should add the quotes to my pathname. I hope anybody can help me with this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By try and error I found a solution:

```
set mys='`\"C:\works pace\prim.exe`\"'
Powershell -Command "Start-Process -FilePath schtasks -ArgumentList '/Create', '/SC ONLOGON', '/TN CoUpdater', '/IT', '/RL HIGHEST', '/TR', \"%mys%\" -verb RunAs"
```

This worked for me and in the task scheduler it is displayed correctly:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a call operator is unnecessary, here's a way that should work:

```
SET "PRIM=""%~dp0prim.exe"""
powershell -Command "Start-Process -FilePath schtasks -ArgumentList '/Create','/SC','ONLOGON','/TN','CoUpdater','/IT','/RL','HIGHEST','/TR','%PRIM%' -Verb runas"
```

Note I embedded the quotes into the environment variable.  As long as there are matching sets of quotes, the cmd parser shouldn't complain.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding that fast. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I get following error: unvalid argument/option with the part of my pathname at wich the first white space occurs

Comment: @Felix Did you copy/paste it verbatim because it worked when I tested it?

Comment: @Felix [Probably because I embedded them incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script). Updated.

Comment: ok now it works, but I am still missing the quotation marks as the first space is interpreted as the argument of the program... How can I fix that?

Comment: What I need is that the path to the executing program is in quotes like this: "C:\Users\workspace 18\prim.exe"