# How to substitute a replacement string for a search string containing =

Tags: batch-file, cmd

[Edited question to try and make clearer]

Simple one, i think....

I am trying to use the following batch code to replace a string in a text file;

```
@echo off
set "replace=#user=guest"
set "replaced=user=StoreUser1"

set "source=C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test.txt"
set "target=C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test1.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal
```

Its not executing as expected, it simply leaves the text unchanged. If however I modify the SET commands (and of course the text in the text file) as;

```
set "replace=#userguest"
set "replaced=userStoreUser1"
```

Then this works as expected. I'm assuming the second '=' which *is required* is causing the SET not to function correctly and needs escaped somehow.

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance!

Adam

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script

Comment: Hi lucumt, I've looked through this post but am struggling to see how I need to adapt my code :(

Comment: What result are you looking for? Please edit your Q to show the expected variable name and expected value in a way that is obvious as to the intent.

Comment: Your question title has nothing to do with your actual question.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to escape the `=` within the find string. So it is impossible to do a variable expansion find/replace if the find string contains `=`.

This was investigated thoroughly at https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1485. Various strategies were explored to get around the problem. But I don't think you want to go down that rabbit hole.

This is one of many reasons why editing text files via batch is generally not a good idea.

You could try PowerShell, I'm sure that would be fairly easy, if you know that scripting language.

Or you could use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is pure script (hybrid JScrpt/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe required. Full documentation is embedded within the script, and available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help. `/jrepl /?help` lists all the various forms of help. For example, `jrepl /?options` gives a brief summary of each option.

```
call jrepl "#user=guest" "user=StoreUser1" /f "C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test.txt" /o "C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test1.txt"
```

or

```
set "replace=#user=guest"
set "replaced=user=StoreUser1"

set "source=C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test.txt"
set "target=C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test1.txt"

call jrepl replace replaced /v /f "%source%" /o "%target%"
```

If you want to overwrite the original file, then

```
set "replace=#user=guest"
set "replaced=user=StoreUser1"

set "source=C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test.txt"

call jrepl replace replaced /v /f "%source%" /o -
```

Comment: @Adam_231 - dbenham does good stuff. It is a lot of work to produce something that can do what `sed` does so easily.