# unable to properly escape double quotes in curl command in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have the following curl command to upload a file to a cloud API.

```
curl -k -w %{http_code} -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data-binary @\\path\to\file.txt https://api.somesite.com/endpoint
```

This curl command works fine if I enter it into a cmd console directly. I need to get it working in a batch file, but when I put the command in the batch file as is, it cannot parse the command (no URL specified). This appears to be due to the double quotes around "Content-Type:text/plain". Having that in the command is critical to the api being able to process my file.

Based on the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script) I have tried a few different ways of escaping the double quotes. These are the results of various methods.

```
^"Content-Type:text/plain^"
```

This does not upload the file, curl error: no URL specified!

```
\"Content-Type:text/plain\"
```

This uploads the file, curl reports success, but the api cannot recognize the file as plain text.

```
""Content-Type:text/plain""
```

This uploads the file, curl reports success, but the api cannot recognize the file as plain text.

```
\""Content-Type:text/plain\""
```

This does not upload the file, curl error: no URL specified!

So I have found many ways to fail but no combination that works for batch, curl and the api together. Are there other methods of escaping I can try or any other suggestions?

Comment: IMO the problem is elsewhere, you'll have to double the `%%`  and I'd double quote nearly all args `curl -k -w %%{http_code} -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data-binary "@\\path\to\file.txt" "https://api.somesite.com/endpoint"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem are not the quotes, but the percent sign.

Inside a batch file, a percent sign that are not part of a value retrieve operation but a literal needs to be escaped by doubling them.

Try with

```
curl -k -w %%{http_code} -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data-binary @\\path\to\file.txt https://api.somesite.com/endpoint
```

The `cmd` parser sees the single `%` as the start of a variable value request and the text after the percent sign is seen as the variable name.

```
curl -k -w %{http_code} -H "Content-Type:text/plain" ....
           ^............................^
           this is a failed variable retrieval operation
```

And this happens both in command line and inside batch files, but the default behaviour for non declared variables is different in both cases. In command line if we request a variable and it does not exist then the parser keeps the variable name, but inside batch files the parser replaces the variable request with an empty string.