# Escaping double quotes in a findstr expression results into wrong output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find the line (or lines, in this case there is only one possible result) containing this expression  `tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = "` in a .java file. I'm using the command
`findstr "tableName_tOracleOutput_. ^= /""  dt_dea_kaspersky.java` directly on the cmd.exe
but the output is not what I expect, as you can see:

```
C:\Users\miguilem\Desktop\test_folder>findstr "tableName_tOracleOutput_. ^= /""  dt_dea_kaspersky.java
                        String tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = null;
                                tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = "dt_dea_kaspersky";
                                tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = dbschema_tOracleOutput_1 + "."
                                        + tableName_tOracleOutput_1
                                                                "mo_dwh/dt_dea_kaspersky_0_1/contexts/"
```

This result would be nearly the same as if I omitted the double quotes at the end of the expressions (giving me results I don t really need, i just want the line that contains the double quotes after the equals and a space).
This is the result of the command with omitted doublequotes that (obviously) does not grant me the single result I want

```
C:\Users\miguilem\Desktop\test_folder>findstr "tableName_tOracleOutput_. ^= "  dt_dea_kaspersky.java
                        String tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = null;
                                tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = "dt_dea_kaspersky";
                                tableName_tOracleOutput_1 = dbschema_tOracleOutput_1 + "."
                                        + tableName_tOracleOutput_1
```

(note the inconsistency of the two outputs, apparently the escaped doublequotes does not get completely ignored, they apparently cause a random additional ghost line STRAIGHT OUTTA NOWHERE, this line (mo_dwh/dt_dea_kaspersky_0_1/contexts/) is not even present in the code nor in a filename anywhere on the whole file system)
I checked the newline characters with notepad++ and it looks as expected (standard CR|LF).

Besides the completely useless official documentation (which literally asks the user to go read about it somewhere else on a not linked command line guide) I checked for information here:

1. [Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script)
2. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php
3. https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html
4. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

At this point I think I missed something very basic, if you need any other information to replicate or solve the problem, don't hesitate to ask! Thanks.

Comment: feel free to read this lengthy explanation of the `FINDSTR` command in your free time: [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i saw it linked in multiple sources while wondering on the FINDSTR hate train, didn't bother reading it at first cause i tought it was uselss to read about "undocumented features" implying those were "additional" features while I couldn't even use basic features out of confusion. A couple lines into it and it already looks worth the read, I suggest the link to anyone using the FINDSTR command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"tableName_tOracleOutput_. ^= /""`  with no more options is interpreted as regular expression string searching case-sensitive for `tableName_tOracleOutput_` with one more character matched by `.` **OR** `=` at beginning of a line **OR** a slash followed by a double quote. The space character in a double quoted search string is interpreted as **OR**.

The command line to use for your search task is:

```
findstr /R /C:"tableName_tOracleOutput_. = "" dt_dea_kaspersky.java
```

The option `/C:` is usually used for a literal search string. But in this case the string inside the double quotes is interpreted nevertheless as regular expression string because of additionally using option `/R` with an important difference in comparison to just `"tableName_tOracleOutput_. = ""`: the space characters are not interpreted as **OR** expressions, but as literal characters.

The `"` at end of search string could be escaped with `\`, but that is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks boss, in the end I messed up a basic mechanic as I guessd, problem is the documentation expects you to guess what "literal" means in "/C:string    Use string as a literal search string (may include spaces).".